# How do I install SciPy on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, numpy, scipy

How do I install SciPy on my system?

For the NumPy part (that SciPy depends on) there is actually an installer for 64 bit Windows: [numpy-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.msi](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.3.0/numpy-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.msi) (is direct download URL, 2310144 bytes).

Running the SciPy superpack installer results in this
message in a dialog box:

> Cannot install. Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry.

I already have Python 2.6.2 installed (and a working Django installation
in it), but I don't know about any Registry story.

The registry entries seem to already exist:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\Help]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\Help\Main Python Documentation]
@="D:\\Python262\\Doc\\python262.chm"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\InstallPath]
@="D:\\Python262\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\InstallPath\InstallGroup]
@="Python 2.6"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\Modules]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\PythonPath]
@="D:\\Python262\\Lib;D:\\Python262\\DLLs;D:\\Python262\\Lib\\lib-tk"
```

---

What I have done so far:

**Step 1**

Downloaded the NumPy superpack installer
numpy-1.3.0rc2-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe
([direct download URL](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.3.0rc2/numpy-1.3.0rc2-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe), 4782592 bytes). Running this installer
resulted in the same message, "Cannot install. Python
version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry.".
**Update**: there is actually an installer for NumPy that works - see beginning of the question.

**Step 2**

Tried to install NumPy in another way. Downloaded the zip
package numpy-1.3.0rc2.zip ([direct download URL](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.3.0rc2/numpy-1.3.0rc2.zip), 2404011 bytes),
extracted the zip file in a normal way to a temporary
directory, D:\temp7\numpy-1.3.0rc2 (where setup.py and
README.txt is). I then opened a command line window and:

```
d:
cd D:\temp7\numpy-1.3.0rc2
setup.py install
```

This ran for a long time and also included use of cl.exe
(part of Visual Studio). Here is a nearly 5000 lines long
[transcript](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/SO/numpyBuildTranscript_2009-10-03.html) (230 KB).

This seemed to work. I can now do this in Python:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random(10)
```

with this result:

```
array([ 0.35667511,  0.56099423,  0.38423629,  0.09733172,  0.81560421,
        0.18813222,  0.10566666,  0.84968066,  0.79472597,  0.30997724])
```

**Step 3**

Downloaded the SciPy superpack installer, scipy-0.7.1rc3-
win32-superpack-python2.6.exe ([direct download URL](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/scipy/scipy/0.7.1rc3/scipy-0.7.1rc3-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe), 45597175
bytes). Running this installer resulted in the message
listed in the beginning

**Step 4**

Tried to install SciPy in another way. Downloaded the zip
package scipy-0.7.1rc3.zip ([direct download URL](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/scipy/scipy/0.7.1rc3/scipy-0.7.1rc3.zip), 5506562
bytes), extracted the zip file in a normal way to a
temporary directory, D:\temp7\scipy-0.7.1 (where setup.py
and README.txt is). I then opened a command line window and:

```
d:
cd D:\temp7\scipy-0.7.1
setup.py install
```

This did not achieve much - here is a [transcript](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/SO/scipyBuildTranscript2.html) (about 95
lines).

And it fails:

```
>>> import scipy as sp2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

---

Platform: Python 2.6.2 installed in directory D:\Python262,
Windows XP 64 bit SP2, 8 GB RAM, Visual Studio 2008
Professional Edition installed.

The startup screen of the installed Python is:

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:46:50) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Value of PATH, result from SET in a command line window:

```
Path=D:\Perl64\site\bin;D:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;D:\Perl\site\bin;D:\Perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;d:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;D:\MassLynx\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Analyst\bin;d:\Python262;d:\Python262\Scripts;D:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\
```

Comment: There are lots of other packages here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  but I don't see one named "SciPy".  I see "ScientificPython" and SciPy subpackages, but not SciPy itself.  Does this mean it's still not available 3 months later, or am I missing something?

Comment: @endolith https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.7.0

Comment: @Inversus: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you may want to download [this version](http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython1.1Py2.5.4) of [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/). It comes with Scipy-0.7.0b1 running on Python 2.5.4.

Comment: Thanks! It works great and is by far the easiest way to get it working (although it is a 32 bit version and thus not a 64 bit version of SciPy). And it doesn't mess with the existing 64 bit version installation of Python.

Comment: For Python 3, a roughly equivalent version is available [here](http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython3.2.5.1/)

Answer (score 63):

Unofficial 64-bit installers for [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

*Make sure that you download & install the packages (aka. wheels) that match your [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) version and [bitness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitness) (ie. `cp35` = Python v3.5; `win_amd64` = x86_64).*

You'll want to **install NumPy first**;  From a CMD prompt with administrator privileges for a system-wide (aka. Program Files) install:

```
C:\>pip install numpy‑<version>+mkl‑cp<ver-spec>‑cp<ver-spec>m‑<cpu-build>.whl
```

***Or*** include the **`--user`** flag to install to the current user's application folder (Typically `%APPDATA%\Python` on Windows) from a **non-admin** CMD prompt:

```
C:\>pip install --user numpy‑<version>+mkl‑cp<ver-spec>‑cp<ver-spec>m‑<cpu-build>.whl
```

Then do the same for SciPy:

```
C:\>pip install [--user] scipy‑<version>‑cp<ver-spec>‑cp<ver-spec>m‑<cpu-build>.whl
```

*Don't forget to replace `<version>`, `<ver-spec>`, and `<cpu-build>` appropriately if you copy & paste any of these examples.  And also that you must use the numpy & scipy packages from the ifd.uci.edu link above (or else you will get errors if you try to mix & match incompatible packages -- uninstall any conflicting packages first [ie. `pip list`]).*

Answer (score 32):

Short answer: Windows 64 bit support is still work in progress at this time. The superpack will certainly not work on a 64-bits Python (but it should work fine on a 32 bits Python, even on Windows 64 bit).

The main issue with Windows 64 bit is that building with mingw-w64 is not stable at this point: it may be our's (NumPy developers) fault, Python's fault or mingw-w64. Most likely a combination of all those :). So you have to use proprietary compilers: anything other than the Microsoft compiler crashes NumPy randomly; for the Fortran compiler, ifort is the one to use. As of today, both NumPy and SciPy source code can be compiled with Visual Studio 2008 and ifort (all tests passing), but building it is still quite a pain, and not well supported by the NumPy build infrastructure.

Comment: Enthought provides 64 bits build of EPD, which is free to use for academic usage (they supported the win64 port), and uses the MKL for speed. There is also another unofficial set of binaries, linked below

Comment: Is 64 bit available for academic use? It would be great - from the website it looks like only 32bit is freely available.

Answer (score 6):

As the transcript for SciPy told you, SciPy isn't really supposed to work on Win64:

```
Warning: Windows 64 bits support is experimental, and only available for
testing. You are advised not to use it for production.
```

So I would suggest to install the 32-bit version of Python, and stop attempting to build SciPy yourself. If you still want to try anyway, you first need to compile BLAS and LAPACK, as PiotrLegnica says. See the transcript for the places where it was looking for compiled versions of these libraries.

Comment: NumPy (at least v1.5.1) doesn't give this warning anymore.

Answer (score 5):

[WinPython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/) is an open-source distribution that has 64-bit NumPy and SciPy.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness:  [Enthought](http://www.enthought.com/) has a Python distribution which includes SciPy; however, it's not free.  Caveat:  I've never used it.

Update: This answer had been long forgotten until an upvote brought me back to it.  At this time, I'll second [endolith's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows/2459784#2459784) of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which is free.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative: http://www.pythonxy.com/

Free and includes lots of stuff meant to work together smoothly.

[This person](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.xy.devel/109) says

> Did you try linux.pythonxy ? ( http://linux.pythonxy.com ).
>
> It's 64 bit ready ...

Though I'm not quite sure what that means.

**Update:**

This appears to be dead. I use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) now, which has 32-bit or 64-bit installers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install Python 2.6.3 over your 2.6.2 (this should also add correct Registry entry), or to register your existing installation [using this script](http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm). Installer should work after that.

Building SciPy requires a Fortran compiler and libraries - [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/index.html).

Comment: When I run Fredrik Lundh's script I get: "*** Unable to register! *** You probably have another Python installation!". I have updated the question with registry entries on my system. (Some of the variables are: pythonpath: 'd:\\Python262;d:\\Python262\\Lib\\;d:\\Python262\\DLLs\\', regpath: 'SOFTWARE\\Python\\Pythoncore\\2.6\\').

Comment: If `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.6\` exists, then try to remove it and run it again. Also - do you run it with enough privileges?

Comment: I tried it and got: "--- Python 2.6 is now registered!". However with the same result when running scipy-0.7.1rc3-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe. Is it expected to work on a 64 bit version of Python? (And yes, I have far too many privileges :-) (administrator). I know I shouldn't for security reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

It is terrible to install such Python data science packages independently on Windows. Try [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows) (one installer, 400 more Python packages, py2 & py3 support). Anaconda really helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have a 32-bit Python 3.5 on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 machine. I just tried almost every way I can find on Stack Overflow and no one works!

Then on [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) I found it. It says:

> SciPy is software for mathematics, science, and engineering.
>
> Requires **numpy+mkl.**
>
> Install numpy+mkl before installing scipy.

**mkl matters!! But nobody said anything about that before!**

Then I installed mkl:

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\a> pip install mkl_service-1.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\****\desktop\a\mkl_service-1.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: mkl-service
Successfully installed mkl-service-1.1.2
```

Then I installed SciPy:

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\a>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\****\desktop\a\scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.18.1
```

It worked~ yeah :)

A tip: You can just google "whl_file_name.whl" to know where to download it~ :)

**Update:**

After all these steps you will find that you still can not use SciPy in Python 3. If you print "import scipy" you will find there are error messages, but don't worry, there is only one more thing to do. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)
——just comment out that line, simple and useful.

```
from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL
```

I promise that it is the last thing to do :)

[image]

PS: Before all these steps, you better install NumPy first. That's very simple using this command:

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Install a Python distribution, http://www.python.org/download/.

Download and install the Anaconda Python distribution.

Make the Anaconda Python distribution link to Python 3.3 if you want NumPy, SciPy or Matplotlib to work in Python 3.3, or just use it like that to have only Python 2.7 and older functionality.

The blog post *[Anaconda Python Distribution Python 3.3 linking](http://infodatatech.blogspot.dk/2013/04/anaconda-python-distribution-python-33.html)* provides more detail about Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error on a 32-bit machine.  I fixed it by registering my Python installation, using the script at:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm

It's possible that the script would also make the 64-bit superpack installers work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either download a scientific Python distribution. One of the ones mentioned [here](https://scipy.org/install.html): https://scipy.org/install.html

Or `pip install` from a whl file [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) if the above is not an option for you.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Answer (score 0):

Okay a lot has been said, but just in case nothing of the previous answers work, you can try;

https://www.scipy.org/install.html

According to them;

> For most users, especially on Windows, the easiest way to install the packages of the SciPy stack is to download one of these Python
> distributions, which include all the key packages:
>
> - [Anacond](https://www.continuum.io/downloads): A
>   free distribution for the SciPy stack. Supports Linux, Windows and
>   Mac.
> - Enthought Canopy: The free and commercial versions
>   include the core SciPy stack packages. Supports Linux, Windows and
>   Mac.
> - Python(x,y) A free distribution including the SciPy
>   stack, based around the Spyder IDE. Windows only.
> - WinPython: A
>   free distribution including the SciPy stack. Windows only.
> - Pyzo: A free distribution based on Anaconda and the IEP interactive
>   development environment. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.

Still for me, Anaconda did solve this problem. Do remember to check the bit (32/64 bit) version before downloading and re-adjust your compiler to the Python implementation installed with the Python distribution you are installing.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, here I am going to share what I have done to install SciPy on my Windows PC without the command line.

> My PC configuration is Windows 7 64-bit and Python 2.7

- **First**  I download the required packages form  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (which version match your configuration EX: cp27==>python2.7 & cp35==>3.5)
- **Second**  I extract the file using [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) (also can be used any zipper like [WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR))
- **Third** I copy the `scipy` folder which I extracted and paste it into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (or put it where the exact location is in your PC like `..\..\Lib\site-packages`)

> NOTE: You have to install NumPy ***first*** before installing SciPy in this same way.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution after days.

Firstly, which Python version you want to install?

If you want for Python 2.7 version:

***STEP 1:***

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.4 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.5 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl

numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.6 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Link: [click](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Once finishing installation, go to your directory.

For example, my directory:

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>
pip install [where/is/your/downloaded/scipy_whl.]
```

***STEP 2:***

> NumPy + MKL

From same web site based on the Python version again:

After that use same thing again in the script folder:

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>

pip3 install [where/is/your/downloaded/numpy_whl.]
```

And test it in the Python folder.

```
Python35>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
```