# install scrapy on win 7 (64-bit)

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, scrapy

I'm trying to install scrapy for python2.6, but it seems not going well. Here is the packages installed:

```
G:\Python26\Scripts>pip freeze
Scrapy==0.16.4
Twisted==12.3.0
libxml2-python==2.7.7
lxml==2.3.6
pyopenssl==0.13
w3lib==1.2
zope.interface==3.8.0
```

I also got iconv and zlib. And this is the log when installing scrapy with pip. I don't know what I should do next, am I missing sth? Need instructions, thank you.

win 7 64-bit, Visual C++ installed

```
C:\Users\d>pip install scrapy
Downloading/unpacking scrapy
  Downloading Scrapy-0.16.4.tar.gz (679kB): 679kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package scrapy
    warning: no files found matching 'license.txt' under directory 'scrapy'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=8.0 in g:\pyt
hon26\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.2 in g:\pytho
n26\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in g:\python26\li
b\site-packages\lxml-2.3.6-py2.6-win32.egg (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in g:\python
26\lib\site-packages\pyopenssl-0.13-py2.6-win32.egg (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0
in g:\python26\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.6-win32.egg (from Twis
ted>=8.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in g:\pytho
n26\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->Twisted>=8.0->scrapy)
Installing collected packages: scrapy
  Running setup.py install for scrapy
    warning: no files found matching 'license.txt' under directory 'scrapy'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
Successfully installed scrapy
Cleaning up...


C:\Users\d>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python26\lib\runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "G:\Python26\lib\runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.engine import ExecutionEngine
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 14, in <modul
e>
    from scrapy.core.downloader import Downloader
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line
16, in <module>
    from .middleware import DownloaderMiddlewareManager
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", lin
e 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request, Response
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <mod
ule>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 9, in <
module>
    import lxml.html
  File "G:\Python26\lib\site-packages\lxml-2.3.6-py2.6-win32.egg\lxml\html\__ini
t__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow the instructions [here](http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7) (also listed above).

The specific DLL error listed in the question is due (at least in my case) to installing the 32 bit OpenSSL with 64 bit everything else. After I installed the correct OpenSSL (and, incidentally, had to uninstall all of the packages in the link above and start over- order matters for the dependency msi installers), scrapy is working fine on python27, windows7, 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through this [guide to installing scrapy on Windows 7](http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7). egenix-pyopenssl is listed as a required package, plus installing pywin32 may also help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Strangely I didn't find python variables in registry, neither in Local_Machine nor in Current_User. I found this question [Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008509/python-version-2-6-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry), and reinstalled python 2.6.6 (32-bit)[link](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/python-2.6.6.msi), yet the result is still same. I then tried this on my old computer(also win7 64-bit), and this problem didn't occurred. I'm now lost again...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did upgrade python which caused this problem.
a simple scrapy upgrade did the trick

> pip install --upgrade Scrapy

Also install correct version of pywin : 
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

My solution is `pip install --upgrade PyopenSSL`

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve this just now and for people who might stumble upon this, the problem is you need PyWin32. For windows users:

1. pip install PyWin32 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32), choose the right python version and 32/64bit. Now in cmd:

   > pip install c:\users\desktop\pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
2. Now, install pywin32 system files, run "python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install" from an elevated command prompt. Run cmd as **admin** and in the command prompt

   > python "C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py" -install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 (64 bit).
The error could be reproduced in Python by:

```
>>> import OpenSSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

After installing pyOpenSSL I got the error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.`, that was solved by copying `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to my path ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443884/2314737)'s my other answer).

Answer (score -1):

Installing `scrapy` is not hard. I just completed it on my Windows 7 machine, which is 64-bit:

Install Python 2.7 from http://python.org/download/ : 
You need to adjust PATH environment variable to include paths to the Python executable and additional scripts. The following paths need to be added to PATH:

```
C:\Python2.7\;C:\Python2.7\Scripts\;
```

To update the PATH open a Command prompt and run:

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py
```

Close the command prompt window and reopen it so changes take effect, run the following command and check it shows the expected Python version:

```
python --version
```

Install pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html
Now open a Command prompt to check pip is installed correctly:

```
pip --version
```

At this point Python 2.7 and pip package manager must be working, let’s install Scrapy:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

Check that scrapy works:

```
scrapy fetch http://www.google.com
```

All of this was derived from: `http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html`

Answer (score -1):

I just met with the same problem but I have already solved it.

Please kindly check your installed python package whether the version(32/64bit) is matched your Python installing version.

Since I am now working in a Scrapy project and I installed a 64bit lxml package to my computer, however, I just found out that the default installing version of Python in my computer is 32bit. Therefore, the version is not matched and the problem you posted would be occurred.