# Getting error: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1 - Python 2.7; Scrapy Module; Importing Cryptography

Tags: python-2.7, dll, module, scrapy

I cannot successfully run the first command in the Scrapy tutorial `(http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)`.  The code copy pasted below is the result (with the error at the end).

**Python 2.7** is installed, and I followed the installation instructions for scrapy `(http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)`. I am running **Python 2.7.6 32 bit on Windows 7 (64 bit)**.

Other aspects of installation:

1. `Twisted-13.2.0.dist-info`
2. `zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7`
3. `Scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7`
4. `lxml-3.3.3-py2.7`
5. `cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7`
6. `cryptography-0.3.dist-info`
7. `pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7`
8. `pywin32_system32`

And here's the error message:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy startproject tutorial
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
      File "twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import default
      File "twisted\internet\default.py", line 56, in <module>
        install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
      File "twisted\internet\default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
        from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
      File "twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import posixbase
      File "twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 24, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
      File "twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 29, in <module>
        from twisted.internet._newtls import (
      File "twisted\internet\_newtls.py", line 21, in <module>
        from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
      File "twisted\protocols\tls.py", line 40, in <module>
        from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\OpenSSL\rand.py", line 11, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 4, in <module>
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py",      l3, in __init__
      self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", l9, in _ensure_ffi_initialized libraries)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\utils.py", line 77, ind_ffi
        ext_package="cryptography",
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 341, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 75, in load_library
        return self._load_library()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 151, in _load_library
        return self._vengine.load_library()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\vengine_cpy.py", line 138, in load_library
        raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)

cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptogr
\_Cryptography_cffi_48bbf0ebx93c91939.pyd': DLL load failed: The operating system cannot
1.**
```

Answer (score 7):

I just reinstall cryptography to make it work.

pip uninstall cryptography

pip install cryptography

Comment: same for me, this is the best advice out there!

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem due to another (older?) version of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll being on the PATH before those of my own OpenSSL 1.0.1g installation. I recommend you use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from SysInternals to monitor python.exe to see where it is actually loading your OpenSSL DLLs from.

In my case, the offender was some Intel components at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\` that came with my drivers. After moving my own OpenSSL bin directory earlier in the `PATH` environment variable, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

this is due to _Cryptography_cffi_48bbf0ebx93c91939.pyd depends on openssl dll ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll. after you compile openssl on windows, u can copy these 2 files to system32.

Answer (score 4):

@crazyzh1984's method is a little complex, but his supplement that posted at the bottom of his answer is very useful. I download the "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1g Light" at http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and then I could install pyOpenSSL successfully.

Answer (score 2):

@lambokini is right，but i'cant comment on the answer, so come this one.

First download openssl source from http://www.openssl.org/

Second start "Visual Studio Command Prompt", compile and install openssl follow install guide(INSTALL.W32 or INSTALL.W64).

Then add "[openssl install path]\bin" to the environment variable "path",
and you can delete ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll under system32.

Notice: dll will be load from the first place it seached.
for exmple: Path=xxx;d:\PHP5;d:\openssl\bin;
if ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll also appears under PHP5,
then python will load that one.

Comment: Binaries for openssl are available from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), works perfectly with python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 2):

I'll write my own take on this due to my extreme frustration and hopes that this might help some other poor chap with his issues getting scrapy to work on windows..

Had a similar issues with faulty libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, or so it would seem, but confirmed it with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

It all went to hell after those dll's were found in System32:
[image]

So i wasnt suffering from wrong `PATH`s (but i did change their order so system32 comes before `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\`.

Next i used [this site](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) the other guys here pointed to. Ive used Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2j Light, since the newer one (1.1.0b) didnt generate these dlls for me for some reason.

Generate them in a different bin folder so you see they are new, and then copy them to system32. Voila, scrapy command line works.

Also, as of today, anaconda's scrapy 1.1.2 does not create a key file for running scrapy commands, ive opened and closed a question about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804652/scrapy-problems-installing-on-clean-anaconda-environment).

Answer (score 2):

As others have said above, there are two .dll files that are loaded instead of the openssl that is downloaded with Scrapy.  Those two .dll files are not compatible.

I resolved this by placing the downloaded .dll files (i used Anaconda to install scrapy) as a higher priority in the Environment Variables as shown in the attached image.

[image: Environment Variables - PATH]

In Environment Variables, within System Variables and the "Path" i placed the Anaconda3 location as shown above at the top and therefore makes it the priority when python comes to load openssl

Comment: Nevster... your a Timesaver! In addition to your solution: its the "PATH" in System Variables you do this trick instead of the "user path" environment. Upvoted!

Comment: Agree with @ZF007, you should use the PATH system variable, instead the user path system variable...

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the other answers, the issue is caused by the two files `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`.
The error occurred when importing OpenSSL in Python

```
>>> from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

Here's how I solved the issue on Windows 10. If you have git for Windows (download [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)) you can just copy these two files from `Git\mingw64\bin\` to some location in your path. What worked for me was to copy them to `c:\Windows` (or else to the folder from which you're starting Python).

To find the locations of the dll files type at a cmd prompt:

```
>where libeay32.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\libeay32.dll
...
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libeay32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error today on a Windows 7 system.  The problem for me was similar to @user2314737, @voetsjoeba, and @Olegp.  libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll where in folders related to Intel that were in the Windows `path` environmental variable.

Unfortunately, my system is locked (work computer), so I could not move the files or alter the system's path variable.  Instead, I manually removed the Intel related items from the path variable that Python accesses using:

```
import os
os.environ['path'] = ';'.join(
    filter(lambda x: 'intel' not in x.lower(), os.environ['path'].split(';'))
    )
import OpenSSL
```