# Scrapy: Problems installing on clean anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, anaconda

On a clean environment of anaconda, after running `conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy` which as of today install scrapy 1.1.2, on python 2.7 for some reason does not create the scrapy-script.py file and scrapy.exe file.

Scrapy does not install correctly, command is unrecognized (obviously)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing a previous scrapy version:

```
conda install -c anaconda scrapy=1.1.1
```

beware, this does not solve other issues with scrapy and anaconda, like pyopenssl issues:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: the operating system cannot run %1.
```