# Windows - 64 Bit - Anaconda3 - Install Scrapy - Error

Tags: python, scrapy

So I installed Scrapy in my Windows system via

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

and it is located in my path

```
C:\Users\******\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe
```

It is added to my env. variable. But when I try and import it into python 3.6.4 or 2.7 I get `No Module Named Scrapy` or `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure was not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it may not work, but take a look at this answer which re-orders the priority of dll files in the env variables.

[Getting error: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1 - Python 2.7; Scrapy Module; Importing Cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800768/getting-error-dll-load-failed-the-operating-system-cannot-run-1-python-2-7/47871199#47871199)