# Pip install Scrapy giving an error on Windows

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy. It is giving me an error code 1. Can anyone help me with this.

`Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\define~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mycaf8\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\define~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-8n6sxr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\define~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mycaf8\lxml`

Comment: post the contents of c:\users\define~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mycaf8\lxml

Comment: Unfortunately, installing Scrapy on Windows is a little bit complicated. See this [ Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765723/install-scrapy-on-win-7-64-bit) You will have to follow this guide: [How to Install Scrapy in 64-bit Windows 7](http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7)

Comment: It gives me the same error when I run Cmd as an administrator

Comment: There is no folder called `define~1` inside `users`

Comment: Did you use `pip install Scrapy`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am using. I just tried `pip install lxml` and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Looks like it's not as easy. You'll have to use [this guide](http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7).