# Enthought Canopy windows registry keys missing

Tags: python, enthought

I installed Enthought Canopy and tried to add the vtk package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
However, the installer does not recognize the python installation.

I believe this has something to do with the registry keys, so a similar problem to this question: [Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008509/python-version-2-6-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry)

Putting the registry keys as recommended to:
C:...\Local Settings\Application Data\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.0.1160.win-x86
makes the python installation visible to the installer, but the installer the hangs up in the next step.

Is this a problem in Canopy or should I take another route to install additional packages which might not be available through easy_install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BROKEN LINK, apologies:] This is a limitation in the current Canopy installers. Another user described a manual workaround here:
https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2013-May/032416.html

---

UPDATE: Aside from being broken, the above is moot:

1) VTK is now a free package for all Canopy users.

2) For other packages not yet available, Gohlke's wheel packages can now be directly installed with pip if Canopy is your default Python. The easiest way to ensure that it is, is to work from a "Canopy Command Prompt" (opened from Start Menu or from the Canopy Tools menu).

3) That is also true in general about how to install 3rd-party packages into Canopy Python.

Comment: Link is now broken. Can you summarize what it once said?

Comment: Apologies for the content-less link. It is, however, moot. I'll revise the answer