# Cannot Install pycURL in Windows 7 64Bit

Tags: python-2.7, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl.  I have downloaded the tar.gz file from here:

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/

I get this error when using easy_install:

```
AssertionError: please check CURL_DIR in setup.py
```

I then tried to manually install the pycurl.exe's from this site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Every single one of these returned this error:

```
"Python versions 2.X required, which was not found in the registry."
```

I'm at a loss.  Can't easy_install, can't manually install.  How should I install this module?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first download libcurl (I think from here) http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=devel&os=Win64
then extract it to some directory (using 7zip)

Then in setup.py set the CURL_DIR parameter (there is comment there on windows users) or use the --curl_dir paramter (see also code there).

hope it will help

Comment: Do you mean I should download the file from your link and then reinstall python after altering setup.py?

Comment: No. I'm referring to using easy_install. Download the package, and then do the changes before running easy_install again

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

haven't tried that one, but you can install python either for all users, or just me, with just me being the default. if you changed that to all users, then a few python libs i have seen (comtypes comes to mind) won't see your python install. you can reinstall as just me, or there are a few hacks here on SO.

did you try both 32 and 64 bit python versions? the library version you install has to match the python install, not necessarily the windows install. you can have a 32 bit python installation on a 64 bit OS installation, but if you try to install the 64 bit library on that combination, it won't see python.

Comment: I've installed for all users, and I have tried installing both the 32 and 64 bit versions.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: ok, then try uninstalling python, and re-installing 'for just me'. or if you absolutely need to install for all users, and are feeling more daring, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008509/python-version-2-6-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry for how to copy the registry entries required to make these work for all users.

Comment: I've just tried that, installed for only me, and I still receive "Python versions 2.X required, which was not found in the registry."