# Installing win32gui python module

Tags: python, win32gui

I am trying to get the name of the window currently in focus by running this code...

```
import win32gui
name = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

However, I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program_1\test.py", line 1, in <module>
import win32gui
ImportError: No module named win32gui
```

I installed pywin32 from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/?source=navbar .
What is the mistake I am making; guessing it is something very basic.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Found the solution.
I was installing a 32bit pywin32 on a 64bit Windows 7 because the 64bit version gave me an error, it could not find the Python registry. I found a solution here [Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008509/python-version-2-6-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry) . Reinstalling Python and installing it just for myself resulted in no errors given by pywin32 64bit installation.

Comment: Did you install pywin32 for the currently installed and running version of Python?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python?

Comment: There is a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version.

Answer (score 36):

See this link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32. It may be of help to you.

**EDIT: (easy version)**

```
Step 1: Download the pywin32....whl
Step 2: pip install pywin32....whl
Step 3: C:\python32\python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Step 4: python
>>> import win32gui
```

[image]