# Cannot install NumPy from a wheel format

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-wheel

I am trying to install [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) from a [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) (.whl) file. I get the error:

> numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Details:

- [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1) pro x64, elevated command prompt
- Python 3.4.2
- Package NumPy from [Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
- File *numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl* copied in the *pip.exe* folder

The log file shows:

> ---
>
> d:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\Scripts\pip run on 01/23/15 11:55:21 
> numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. 
> Exception information: 
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main 
> status = self.run(options, args) 
> File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run 
> InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None)) 
> File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 167, in from_line 
> raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename) 
> pip.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you open `python` and run `import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())`?

Comment: [('cp34', 'none', 'win32'), ('cp34', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('cp33', 'none', 'any'), ('cp32', 'none', 'any'), ('cp31', 'none', 'any'), ('cp30', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]

Comment: It doesn't seem to have the tags in the filename of the `.whl` so perhaps this file isn't for your platform?

Comment: What do you get when you run `import platform; print(platform.platform())`? Perhaps your system isn't being detected properly as 64-bit.

Comment: It reports: Windows-8-6.2.9200

Comment: "It doesn't seem to have the tags in the filename of the .whl so perhaps this file isn't for your platform?" - my file name is ...cp34... and the supported tags include "('cp34', 'none', 'any')"  - shouldn't then this whl file be supported?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69451/discussion-between-lmsasu-and-simeon-visser).

Comment: Much later: I decided to use the anaconda distribution. It comes with plenty of packages preinstalled. Other packages can be added through pip (I already did this, with some github packages).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Short answer: rename the file to `numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win32.whl` to install it.

You can check what tags your `pip` tool accepts for installation by running:

```
import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

In this case pip is incorrectly detecting your operating system to be 32-bits and the file you're trying to install was `win_amd64` in its filename.

If you rename the file to `numpy-1.9.1%2Bmkl-cp34-none-win32.whl` (which now contains the tags that are considered supported) then you can install the package. It's a trick because the file is still built for 64-bits but this allows you to install the package as intended.

Comment: After a real-time chat with Simeon, the problem was solved - thanks. Now the question is: how could I convince the pip system to see my machine as a x64 system - as it actually is? On x64 platform I could benefit from the 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: @lmsasu: it's possibly related to this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue18987 - are you running a 32-bits Python interpreter on a 64-bits OS? Or, if not, we may have found a related but different bug. pip calls `distutils.utils.get_platform()` to determine the platform.

Comment: Strange, but the winpython distribution shows [('cp34', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp34', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('cp33', 'none', 'any'), ('cp32', 'none', 'any'), ('cp31', 'none', 'any'), ('cp30', 'none', 'any'), <etc>] so the cp34 with windows x64 is seen here. Note that winpython comes with numpy included.

Comment: Now if you upgrade to pip 8.0.2+ , then the problem is solved. To upgrade on windows see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29886593/2182047) too.

Comment: The *filename* matters??  That's dumb.  Doesn't it have metadata inside the file to tell what version it goes with?  Mine was failing because the file was named `scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-cp27-none-win32_001.whl` by a download manager.

Comment: @endolith: consider a package index - the filename is used to determine what package to download for the platform that's trying to install it. The installer (pip) won't download / open all files to determine what file to install so the metadata should be located outside the file somehow.

Comment: I couldn't install neither 32 or 64 bit wheel packages of different libraries for Python 3.4, and this solved the issue. The general solution is to change the `cp34m` part in the .whl filename to `none`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your operating system. Install Python 64bit not 32bit.

Comment: GREAT!! Best answer!

Comment: This no longer works, you need to use: `python3 -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())" |sed -zE 's/\),/),\n/g'`.

Comment: `pip debug --verbose` this is easier, replace name of the file with something out  of this list

Answer (score 18):

After several tests I think the problem is "win32" or "amd64" itself. I tried replacing those two with "any" and it worked.

Comment: You absolute legend, thank you. Saved me so much more inevitable agony.

Comment: Thank you! I hope one day such a ridiculous error will be fixed.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the workaround to install [*gohlke* packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) on Python (3.4.4 (AMD64)) was to change the "cp34m" part rather than the "win*" parts in previous answers:

```
python -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())":
```

```
[('cp34', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'),
('cp34', 'none', 'any'), ...
```

`ls -ld *`:

```
matplotlib-2.0.0b3-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
pandas-0.18.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

Change the above names to:

```
matplotlib-2.0.0b3-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
pandas-0.18.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

For example, `pip install matplotlib-2.0.0b3-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`

```
Processing ...
...Successfully installed matplotlib-2.0.0b3
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to the list of other possible solutions, I had to upgrade pip itself. The latest binary from [Gholke's site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) had the "cp27m" tag, which didn't show up when I checked the pip tags using:

```
import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

After I upgraded pip, the wheel didn't work, but just doing a regular `pip install numpy` worked.

Comment: After the upgrade I've managed to install the wheel on the first try.!

Comment: @lmsasu this is the correct answer: update pip `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 3):

If you have, say, Python 3.4 installed, make sure to install the `-cp34-` version of the wheel and not `-cp35-`.

Answer (score 2):

The current *[WinPython](https://github.com/stonebig/winpython)* package manager need a two-characters fix to accept to recognize the new NumPy + mkl 'wheel'.

https://github.com/stonebig/winpython/commit/5e13230609a2e9f4d66d98c3776207ce4b4dd050

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, uninstall the NumPy package:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

Then install it again from cache:

```
pip install numpy
```

I had the same problem with several packages after upgrading from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the directory where your `'pip.py'` sits and then type following on the Windows command line:

```
..\python.exe pip.py install name_of_package.whl
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and tried to work it out with the suggested solutions.

I changed *win64* to *win32* and it didn't work either. But then I changed the name to original and this time it worked! The only extra thing I did was to go offline. That's so strange.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your operating system. Uninstall Python 32-bit and install Python 64-bit rather or alternatively find a 32-bit [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) file.