# How to install this wheel?

Tags: python, pygame, pip, python-3.4, python-wheel

I managed to install pip but when I use pip to install the downloaded wheel, it prints:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Requirement 'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

The file is in the same folder (Scripts) with pip.

I did try to use the `wheel` tool too:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\wheel install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wheel\tool\__init__.py", line 358, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wheel\tool\__init__.py", line 301, in install_f
    args.wheel_dirs, args.force, args.list_files)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wheel\tool\__init__.py", line 202, in install
    raise WheelError("No such wheel file: {}".format(req))
wheel.tool.WheelError: No such wheel file: pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\wheel.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wheel\tool\__init__.py", line 361, in main
    sys.stderr.write(e.message + "\n")
AttributeError: 'WheelError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

I use PowerShell, please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `pip` to install wheel files using the full path:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install C:\Python34\Scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Without the path the name is seen as a requirement rather than a already-downloaded file. This should work for wheel files that support your current Python architecture. You can verify your architecture with:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())"
```

This should print `win_amd6`. If it prints `win32` instead, you have a 32-bit Python binary and need to pick a different wheel.

Comment: Yes I use Python 3.4.2 I think, 3.4 in general, 64-bit version and about if it is bound or not, i think it is

P.S I used C:\Python34\Scripts> .\pip install -f --trusted-host http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ pygame but it printed an error at the unpacking part

Comment: Collecting http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
  Downloading http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (1.0MB)
    100% |################################| 1.0MB 2.6MB/s ta 0:00:01
  Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Ded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-prlwv8rf-unpack\pythonlibs (downloaded from C:\Users\Ded\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-nviu9vhg-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
  Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Ded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nviu9vhg-build

Comment: Why did you use `--trusted-host` in between the `-f` switch and the URL?

Comment: Because otherwise it doesnt let me start the download :/

Comment: @DedSecz: the `--trusted-host` argument is a separate switch: `pip install --trusted-host www.lfd.uci.edu -f http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ pygame`.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters Look at this, I am confused :\ : https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmdvngw8l6f1qa1/Screenshot%202015-01-26%2015.31.04.png?dl=0

Comment: @DedSecz: the command is either `.\pip` or `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip`, not something with spaces in between. :-)

Comment: @Martjin Pieters, well yes, but "this wheel is not supported on this platform?" what?

Comment: @DedSecz: what does `C:\Python34\Scripts\python -c 'import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())'` print?

Comment: @Martjin This: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k44omh9wjqy41z4/Screenshot%202015-01-26%2015.40.19.png?dl=0

Comment: @DedSecz: That's because the command `python` is not found. I gave you a different command however, use `C:\Python34\Scripts\python`.

Comment: @DedSecz: by the way, you don't need to use my name in the comment, since this is my answer post I get notified anyway. That way you don't have to worry about how to spell my name either. I see you also used the command from my comment but had left a `cd` on the line, so that broke.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont get what u mean, I did write C:\.. python on powershell without doing any cds, just opened it and still same thing, look: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l26qomqk5nmyne/Screenshot%202015-01-26%2015.47.03.png?dl=0

Comment: @DedSecz: ah, I see I got the path to your Python interpreter wrong. Does `python.exe` work?

Comment: @DedSecz: next attempt: `C:\Python3.4\python -c 'import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())'`

Comment: python.exe doesnt work, but if I go a subdirectory above (remove Scripts) it works like a charm, let me test the last line you sent me.

EDIT: I used the line u sent me and it worked great, it printed "win32"

Comment: @DedSecz: then you have a Python *32-bits installation*, not a 64-bit. You'll need to pick the correct wheel accordingly.

Comment: Oh damn.. good point, I am so dumb. Now I noticed it is 32 bit. I thought it was 64bit though haha, thanks a lot, let me try the 32-bit pygame and update u with results

Comment: It worked like a charm! Package successfully installed! Thanks a lot Martijn!

Comment: There might be a bug in pip (or somewhere else) as similar things are happening to others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format/28111899#28111899 (64-bits not being detected)

Comment: @SimeonVisser: this isn't a 64-bit Python install.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: remember that you can install a 32-bit Python executable on a 64-bit Windows machine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the bug is that for 32-bit interpreter on 64-bit OS it would report "win32" on Windows but not on other platforms - hence if it reports "win32" that doesn't mean it can't install a 64-bit wheel, it's only a bug in deciding whether the wheel can be installed.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: yeah, I haven't seen that happen yet though. So far I only have had people with 32-bit Python installations (on 64-bit windows) and / or using the wrong pip (`pip -V` shows that they are using a different Python version).

Answer (score 2):

pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

this worked on my computer with Python2.7.3(64bit) while other versions not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Install wheel support for `pip`:

```
pip install wheel
```

Install the downloaded wheel:

```
pip install path/to/pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: They clearly already have wheel support installed as that's part of the traceback of the second attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the 64bit python and install the 32bit version to solve this issue.

```
c:\python34\scripts\pip install c:\users\USER\downloads\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
Unpacking c:\users\USER\downloads\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame
Cleaning up...
```

Worked fine with 32bit :)