# python wheel file install TA_lib*.whl

Tags: python, python-wheel

I am trying to install the 'TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-*.whl' file with powershell (windows). I receive the message 'file ... looks like a filename, but the file does not exist'.

I run '`pip install C:\Programs\TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-*.whl`' from `C:\Programs>` where the whl file is located.

I use python 2.7, yet I also tried with file '`TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp34-*.whl`' with same result.

I looked online and at SO, for similar cases, but so far everything I tried keeps giving me the same red error message 'TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-*.whl is not a valid wheel filename'.

EDIT:
the full message I receive in powershell is the following:

'Requirement 'C:\Programs\TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-*.whl is not a valid wheel filename.'

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Instead of paraphrasing the error message, could you copy and paste the exact error message?  e.g. if it's `looks like a filename, but the file does not exist xyz.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` please put that exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install this wheel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150738/how-to-install-this-wheel)

Comment: @ Brian Cain: Please see my edit above

Comment: @ Brian Cain: this is not a duplicate, as I looked already at this SO message

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me is to write the full name of the file, instead of using '*' after the beginning of the file name. 'pip install' command works fine with the full name of the wheel (.whl) file - in this instance.