# Python pip install exact version if two versions, one generic and one local, exist

Tags: python, pip

We have set up a local python package server for your internal python packages and serve also some packages which are hard to compile on windows. As numpy is one of these packages, there exist now two versions of numpy on our server:

- numpy-1.13.0-cp35-none-win32.whl
- numpy-1.13.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

How can I instruct pip to install a specific version of these two? Running `pip install numpy` will pick the package with "mkl", but for some projects I want numpy without "mkl".

Edit:

The only way which works is the full URL to the package, which seems a little bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember, it's just a matter of writing the package's entire name.

If you need a guide:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples

Comment: Which example do you mean? If I use `pip install "numpy==1.13.0"`the "mkl" version is used. Other variants I've tried result in a error. Whats working is the full URL, but this seems a little bit verbose...

Comment: pip install numpy-1.13.0-cp35-none-win32.whl

Comment: This gives a error: `Requirement 'numpy-1.13.0-cp35-none-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist`. I also tried to delete the extension and further components of the name, but none of the names could be resolved to a package.

Comment: Dude, seems you'll have to stick with the URL approach...
If you use wheel you might bump into this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150738/how-to-install-this-wheel

Comment: Forgot to ask: can you write a requirements.txt for this?
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Maybe you can just write the complete path inside the file (--find-links or --extra-index-url) and use pip install -r requirements.txt with the package name inside the file too.

Comment: Yea, i use a requirements file. I just copy pasted the complete URL to the requirements file.