# Installing numpy from wheel format: "...is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip, python-wheel

I realize a question that relates to this has already been asked at [Cannot install numpy from wheel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format/28460036#28460036) , but the solution presented there does not work for me. I have asked on that thread too (by answering!) but I'm not getting any replies, so here goes:

I have been trying to install matplotlib, but I first need to install numpy. I downloaded the file `numpy-1.8.2+mkl-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl`, then tried to install it using pip. The error message I keep getting is:

"numpy-1.8.2+mkl-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform". The solution suggested by the thread I referenced above, was to replace "_amd64" by "32", making the filename numpy-1.8.2+mkl-cp26-none-win32.whl. This did not work either, and I get exactly the same error as above.

Any suggestions?

I use Python 3.4.2 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You need the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to build the wheel.

Comment: OK, thanks. I formatted my hard drive recently, and I lost all those utilities I always took for granted :/

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: You shouldn't need a compiler to *install* the wheel.

Comment: @BrenBarn but I need a compiler to run/use the wheel?

Comment: @KonradKapp: No, you shouldn't need a compiler to use it at all.  You need a compiler to *create* the wheel file, but that's not something an end user would normally be doing.  (You would only be creating a wheel file if you're the one writing/distributing the library.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "cp26" in that filename means "CPython 2.6".  If you're using Python 3.4 you'll need a file that has "cp34" in the filename.

Comment: They should clarify this :p I got caught up in 32 vs 64 and didn't look further for reasons unknown

Comment: Thanks, this saved my time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.1/numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe/download).

Comment: Alas, it says that I need Python 3.4 installed, and that it did not find it in the registry, but I am 100% certain that it installed correctly since I am using it, and Windows also lists it in my list of programs in the control panel

Comment: If it's not in the registry, then you've clearly done something wrong. I'd try repairing your installation.