# installing numpy from wheel format on windows ( not a supported wheel on this platform.)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-wheel

[Installing numpy from wheel format: "...is not a supported wheel on this platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460783/installing-numpy-from-wheel-format-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platfor?rq=1)

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions suggested resolved my issue.

First, just like everybody else, i went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#jpype and downloaded `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` since my windows 10 is 64bit and my python is 2.7.

Then i set the path to where the file is  `cd Desktop` and then typed `pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`.

In return i get `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Then, i wanted to make sure that i was running the correct whl file. So, i typed `python` in the terminal window to check the version and whatnot and got the following message `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

It puzzles me that it says `win32` when I have windows 10 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Either way, i tried `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl', to no avail.

Comment: What error message do you get for the "win32" wheel file? I'd expect that one to work, since you have a 32-bit python installed

Comment: @Blckknght i get the exact same error message `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Hmm, I tried reinstalling my copy of numpy and was getting the same error. Then I upgraded pip (as it was prompting me) and with the new version, the install worked fine. Perhaps try that?

Answer (score 9):

Upgrade your pip

> > python -m pip install --upgrade pip

and try installing again using pip

> > pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue with Windows 10 - 64 bit.
I downloaded the "numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl" then rename it to "numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl" and installed using pip.  It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

me too .
same problem.
I try change to name a whl file.

numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
->numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem multiple times on my windows 10 64 bit platform with python 2.7 - I attempt to install the win_amd64.whl and get this same error:

```
numpy-1.12.0b1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

rasterio-1.0a3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

If i rename to win32.whl, the install works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install python 32-bit with no matter on 32/64-bit system.
Please try to download and install with pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl or numpy-1.10.4+vanilla-cp27-none-win32.whl The later one maybe work.