# Installing numpy for Windows 10: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-import

I am new to `Python` and am attempting unsuccessfully to install `numpy`.  The current problem is an error message reading, in part, `Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed`.  I cannot locate this error message on the internet and am asking for help.  The complete error message is at the bottom of this post.

First I thought I should provide system and version details and describe what I have done.  I am running `Windows 10` on a 64-bit machine and have installed `Python 2.7.13` from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

I have also installed `Anaconda`, also for `Python 2.7` and a 64-bit machine, downloaded from here https://www.continuum.io/downloads.  `Anaconda` runs `Python 2.7.12`, rather than `Python 2.7.13`.  When I type `import numpy` inside the `Anaconda` GUI `IPython` no errors or warnings appear.  Nevertheless, I have the impression running `numpy` from inside `Python 2.7.13` using `IDLE (Python GUI)` might be computationally faster.  `Python 2.7.13` appears first in my Path statement.

I downloaded `numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#jpype  Following suggestions from this post [installing numpy from wheel format on windows ( not a supported wheel on this platform.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839198/installing-numpy-from-wheel-format-on-windows-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-pl?rq=1) I renamed:

`numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` to:
`numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl`

manually by clicking on the name and editing it.  The renamed file is in the folder `C:\Python27`

Then I used the Windows command window (cmd) to update `pip` typing:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

A message said `pip` was already up-to-date.

Then I typed the following in the cmd window:

```
pip install numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

A message said: `Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl`.  (Prior to doing this I attempted to install the `.whl` file using its original name and received an error that the file was not for my platform.)

After installing `numpy` in `Python 2.7.13` I open `Python` and typed:

```
import numpy
```

Here is the complete error message that was returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Numerous `numpy` folders and files now appear inside `C:\Python27`

I also tried the following two commands and received the messages shown:

```
>>> pip show numpy
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> git clean -xdf
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Sorry that this post is so long, but I do not know which of the above details might be most helpful in diagnosing the problem.  I have only been using `Python` for about 24 hours and most of that time has been spent attempting to install `numpy` into `Python 2.7.13`.  Mostly I use `R` and know some `C`.  I have not attempted to install any other `Python` libraries or packages.  Perhaps I am missing dependencies required by `numpy`.  Thank you for any advice or assistance with this problem.  If I can provide additional information please let me know.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: The last commands (pip and git) are not python commands. You should call them outside the python shell.
Besides I think anaconda already has numpy installed. Try to remove what you installed with pip and import numpy again.

Comment: The only thing I have installed with `pip` is `numpy-1.12.0rc2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl`.  Is that what I should uninstall?  I installed `Anaconda` with its own installation application that came with the download from the `Anaconda` website.  Should I try uninstalling `Anaconda` instead?  Prior to installing the `.whl` file there were virtually no files inside the folder `C:\Python27` and `import numpy` returned a single syntax error.

Comment: try to unnistall that numpy you installed. Anaconda comes with pre installed packages and one of them is numpy

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer I understand that.  `Numpy` works in `Anaconda`.  My preference is to run it in `Python 2.7.13` because I have the impression, perhaps the incorrect impression, that computation power and speed is better in `Python 2.7.13`.  How can I install `numpy` in `Python 2.7.13` downloaded from the `Python` webpage?

Comment: @cgohlke Please provide a link to the file `numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl`.  I am unable to locate it.

Comment: @cgohlke I tried that file last night after posting, but unfortunately it did not work either.

Comment: You already *have a working installation of numpy*. Why are you trying to go through the painful process of installing numpy manually on Windows? That's what Anaconda is *for*. Why do you think running it in IDLE will be "computationally faster"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I have read repeatedly that the free version of `Anaconda` does not have the computation power of `Python 2.7.13` from the Python webpage.

Comment: "the computation power' what??? Where have you read this, what are you talking about? Are you sure you've even installed numpy with the proper BLAS backend?

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure you `conda` provides Python 2.7.13

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No I am not sure I have even installed `numpy` with the proper BLAS backend.  As for computation power of the free version of `Anaconda`, I was under the impression that the free version was not connected to an `Intel` chip that would optimize performance.  However, I might be wrong about that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do not even know what a BLAS backend is, let alone what a proper BLAS backend is.  I am learning on my own as fast as I can over the last three days.  Almost everything I know is documented in my answer below.

Comment: My Anaconda python currently comes with the MKL compiled BLAS and LAPACK functions, I believe. Check `numpy.__config__.show()`. The output is a bit cryptic, but looks for `MKL`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There was ouput for four topics: `lapack_opt_info:`, `blas_opt_info:`, `lapack_mkl_info:` and `blas_mkl_info:`.  All four seemed to have the same output: `libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']`

Answer (score 8):

In my case this issue was related to numpy. So, I removed the numpy and again installed it. To remove numpy if you already have conda environment can we done by `conda remove numpy` if this command is removing some other packages also which are dependent on numpy then in the same environment if pip is installed, numpy can be removed using pip `pip uninstall numpy` and to again download it use `pip install numpy`. This should probably fix your error.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issues on Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, numpy was only installed using pip but your answer put me on the right path. I did a conda install numpy and it resolved the issue!

Answer (score 5):

This issue was discussed extensively over on https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272 with a workaround solution which worked for me.  It's pertinent to the Anaconda environment I believe you have.

Quoting:
tobigithub commented on Jul 23, 2017.
@njsmith
thank you, I just confirmed using a VM on a clean Windows 10 system that has never seen Intel MKL DLLs, numpy or conda, all things are fine and numpy works. I am just puzzled how numpy suddenly stopped working, could be third parties. Probably needs some more digging, lets see what we can find out to make numpy ironclad to any dependency issue.

The solution is indeed related to some DLL depencency issues under WIN with Intel MKL libraries
the numpy import error was under python 3.6.2 and numpy 1.13.1 :

"import numpy"
numpy\core_init_.py", line 16, in
from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

The quick and dirty solution is to copy all Intel mkl*.dll libraries from the specific environments (env) subfolder (seen at stackoverflow)

<\Library\bin> to
<\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core>

```
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        30,277,392 mkl_avx.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        38,253,840 mkl_avx2.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        42,234,640 mkl_avx512.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        45,722,896 mkl_avx512_mic.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        25,369,360 mkl_core.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        24,541,456 mkl_def.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        24,506,640 mkl_intel_thread.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        29,744,400 mkl_mc.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        30,594,320 mkl_mc3.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        12,567,824 mkl_rt.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        11,388,688 mkl_sequential.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        12,575,504 mkl_tbb_thread.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        11,250,960 mkl_vml_avx.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        11,463,952 mkl_vml_avx2.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        10,285,840 mkl_vml_avx512.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM        11,692,304 mkl_vml_avx512_mic.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM         5,224,208 mkl_vml_cmpt.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM         5,345,552 mkl_vml_def.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM         9,477,904 mkl_vml_mc.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM         9,368,336 mkl_vml_mc2.dll
04/13/2017  12:50 AM         9,593,616 mkl_vml_mc3.dll
```

now numpy can be imported and runs fine.  One last thing, the best approach is to match compatible versions of Python and numpy, which of course change as releases are made. See [numpy compatibility index] (https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0029-deprecation_policy.html) for up to date compatibility information.  Don't forget to match scipy and matplotlib versions to numpy as well.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have gotten `numpy` installed for `Python 2.7.13` on the `Windows 10` 64-bit computer using the following steps.  I was able to install `numpy` for either a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of `Python 2.7.13`.  Instructions for both are provided.

At the top of this answer are my instructions for 32-bit `Python`.
In the middle are my instructions for 64-bit `Python`.
At the bottom are my instructions for 64-bit `Python` using a wheel file.

I suspect the primary problem in my original post may have arisen from not realizing that apparently the default version of `Python` that is downloaded from here (https://www.python.org/downloads/) is 32-bit.

**For installing `numpy` on 32-bit `Python 2.7.13`**

1. uninstalled `Anaconda`
2. removed `Anaconda` from `User Variables` in the `Environment Variables` window
3. installed `Python 2.7.13` from the official Python website: https://www.python.org/
4. in command window typed:

   C:\users\general1>cd:\python27
5. Attempted to update `pip` in command window although `pip` was already up to date:

   python -m pip install -U pip
6. in command window used the following command, which returned a huge number of errors:

   pip install numpy
7. in command window typed:

   python -m pip install numpy

Step 7 seems to have worked.  It returned the following message:

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) 
  after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.',
  error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly 
  closed by the remote host'))': /simple/numpy/
  Downloading numpy-1.12.0-cp27-none-win32.whl (6.6MB)
    100% |################################| 6.6MB 64kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0
```

8. Opened `Python 2.7.13` and typed:

   import numpy

Only the command prompt was returned.  No errors or warnings were issued.

I have not yet tried to use any code that requires `numpy`, but at least it seems to have been installed.

Step 7 says that a 32-bit file was downloaded:

```
numpy-1.12.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

I do not know whether a 32-bit version of `numpy` was installed or a 64-bit version.  Perhaps the file is a 64-bit version that was renamed to say it was a 32-bit version as described in my question.

I typed in `Python` (from [Do I have Numpy 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553549/do-i-have-numpy-32-bit-or-64-bit)):

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.platform_bits
32
```

So, it seems a 32-bit version of `numpy` was installed although my `Python` is supposed to be a 64-bit version (from here: [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)):

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
'32bit'
```

Perhaps in all of the installing and uninstalling of `Python` I accidentally installed a 32-bit version the last time.  I can try installing `Python` again and use the intended 64-bit version this time.  Hopefully the same steps above will still work.

Perhaps if I want a 64-bit version of `Python 2.7.13` I am to click on the following on the official `Python` webpage (here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/):

```
Download Windows x86-64 MSI installer
```

instead of on the prominent (https://www.python.org/downloads/):

```
Download Python 2.7.13
```

I am also curious to know from where the file `numpy-1.12.0-cp27-none-win32.whl` was downloaded.  I will provide that too if I find out.  Maybe it was downloaded from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

**For installing `numpy` on 64-bit `Python 2.7.13`**

The steps above worked for installing `numpy` for what turned out to be a 32-bit version of `Python 2.7.13`.

To install numpy for a 64-bit version of `Python 2.7.13` I used the following steps:

1. uninstall `Python 2.7.13`
2. Download: `python-2.7.13.amd64.msi` by clicking on: `Download Windows x86-64 MSI installer` from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
3. in command window typed:

   C:\users\general1>cd:\python27
4. Attempted to update `pip` in command window although `pip` was already up to date:

   python -m pip install -U pip
5. in command window used the following command, which this time did not return any errors:

   pip install numpy

which returned:

```
C:\Python27>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.12.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (7.5MB)
    100% |################################| 7.5MB 63kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0
```

6. Opened `Python 2.7.13` and typed:

   import numpy

No errors or warnings were returned.

7. Checked whether `numpy` was 64-bit or 32-bit.  It was 64-bit.

   import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo

   sysinfo.platform_bits

   64

**For installing `numpy` wheel files in `Python 2.7.13`**

After installing `numpy` I tried to install `scipy` and received an error: `numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found` (described here [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)).

I did the following:

1. Uninstalled `Python 2.7.13`
2. Installed `Visual Studio Community 2017 RC` as described by drewid (here: [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found))
3. Installed `VCForPython27.msi` also as described by drewid.

Then I received a `scipy` error `cannot import name NUMPY_MKL` mentioned here ([ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)).

I downloaded the files `numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` and `scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy as suggested by VMAtm.

Then I:

1. uninstall `Python 2.7.13`
2. Reinstall `Python 2.7.13` using `python-2.7.13.amd64.msi`
3. Installed `numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy using the following line in the command window:

   pip install numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
4. Installed `scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy using the following line in the command window

   pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Both `numpy` and `scipy` can now import inside `Python 2.7.13`

Note that I placed `scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` and `numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` in the folder `c:\Python27` prior to using the aforementioned `pip` commands.

```
C:\>cd\Python27

C:\Python27>pip install numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\python27\numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0+mkl

C:\Python27>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\python27\scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.18.1

C:\Python27>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with the following steps:

1. Creating and activating a new `conda` environment
2. Installing `numpy` within the environment
3. Then using this environment for my
   project

I was using `PyCharm` so to execute (3), I just set the project interpreter to the Python interpreter in the new environment I created in (1).