# numpy wheel is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to install numpy from a wheel file.
The wheel name is `numpy-1.16.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

However when I do:

```
pip install --user --no-index --find-links /my/folder  /my/folder/numpy-1.16.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

I got

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
numpy-1.16.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Now I have seen answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460861/4451521) where it says to verify that the "cp36" matches my system

```
python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

As you can see my python is 3.6.3 so the cp36 part seems to match

What else can I do to understand this problem and solve it?

EDIT:
As per request

```
uname -a
Linux login01 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 16:09:20 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT2:

I noticed some strange error messages with other packages so I did

```
pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Isn't is strange. The `python --version` is 3.6.3

Also , there seems not to be a `pip3`

Comment: Any particular reason why you need a `--user` install from a wheel file when you are running anaconda?

Comment: @FlyingTeller No. I was just instructed to do so. Does it have any influence?

Comment: If using Conda, preferably use Conda to install packages: `conda install numpy` or something along those lines. With `pip`, you're mixing up two package managers. That might work, but it may also cause issues.

Comment: `--user` shouldn't hamper your installation; I don't think that is an issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to install this specific wheel/binary of NumPy? Why not Conda or Pip find a NumPy version for you, and install that? Often, you can even indicate to Conda or Pip a version or version range for a package.

Comment: What is the result of `uname -a`? That will give us some information about your system, so we can see if that matches.

Comment: this particular computer does not (and will not by policy that I do not control) have access to internet. I am provided with the wheel file

Comment: Please add the information to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: try running `python3 -m pip debug --verbose` to get the list of compatible tags for your system and check if that matches with the one you have.

Comment: I noticed something and updated the question. Please take a look

Comment: Does `python -m pip --version` give you the correct pip?

Comment: @FlyingTeller  Yes! It seems so! `pip 9.0.1 from /spring/envs/r0.3.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: so I guess I should replace all pips by `python -m pip`??

Comment: Either that or you could just install pip3 using `apt-get -y install python3-pip`

Comment: It is a bit odd that you have Python from Anaconda, but then the system pip. But if `python -m pip` works, use that. I wouldn't use a system-installed `python3-pip` package as suggested, since that would also conflict with the Anaconda version. (Plus you may not be able to install system packages.)

Comment: *always* update pip to the latest available version `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. As the pip version also determines which wheels can be installed.