# Installing kivy with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, kivy, python-3.4

I get this error when trying to install kivy.

```
kivy-1.8.9-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform.
```

I run Python 3.4 and have installed these modules:

```
Pip 6.0.8
Pygame 1.9.2a0
Setuptools 14.3.1
```

Which is all the latest, so i have no idea what the problem is. I am so excited to create application, with kivy! Annoy me so much that i just can't install it.

I have been following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYNWK2GpwgA&index=1&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe_l6XiJ40yGTEqIKugAdTy) by Sentdex, if anyone is familiar with it.

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro, 64bit

Comment: Can you add information about your OS? Windows/OSX/Linux 32/64 bit?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: Can you have a look at this answer and see if `pip` correctly identifies your OS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28111899/2272172

Comment: I did get it installed, but just tried to run a simple program and it throws me this error: `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not valid Win32-program.` (translated from Danish) when i run this line:
`from kivy.app import App`

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that you are running a `64bit` system? All these errors usually turn up, when you try to install a `64bit` binary on a `32bit` system.

Comment: 100% sure, i tried installing kivy before, but threw me the same error then i totally removed Python and installed it once again, which still don't work.. But it is "installed" now, i can do `Import kivy` but not `from kivy.app import App`

Comment: Note, that the solution in the answer I linked before is actually cheating: Your python interpreter thinks that this is a 32bit installation and therefore refused to install a 64bit binary. Renaming the binary tricked the interpreter into assuming that this binary is 32 bit which it is not. Can you post what `sys.maxsize` prints? Maybe you installed a 32 bit version of python? I am not sure if that would raise that kind of error, though.

Comment: Oh i okay i see. Well when i do `print(sys.maxsize)` it gives me this `2147483647`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73649/discussion-between-cel-and-rasmusgp).

Answer (score 2):

How to install Kivy on windows 10

1. Download wheels from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (you have to download both `pygame` and `kivy`, if you are running 32 bit python3.5 then download `Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp35-none-win32.whl` and `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl` or choose the appropriate one for your needs.)
2. Place installed wheels into same folder.
3. Run (Windows) `CMD` as administrator and go into created folder by using cmd (where you placed your wheels)
4. pip install by copy/paste name of the wheel and push the enter button. For example: `pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl` and `pip install Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp35-none-win32.whl`
5. Now you can use *Kivy*

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I had a similar problem and found that the file name of the wheel is of dire importance. I had downloaded a duplicate copy of the wheel and Windows had auto-renamed it with the suffix "(2)". Using the original file name without this suffix did the trick. Hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the python location and the python lib on the path in 
environment variable.

ex: path:

```
C:python/python3.4;
C:python/python3.4/lib
```