# Python Django installing mysql: easy_install and pip errors

Tags: python, mysql, django

Trying to `python manage.py syncdb` but it gives me an error. Similar to a lot of other questions on here, but the solutions provided do not solve the error after I install them.

My `settings.py` file inside my project directory

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'network',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '', #EMPTY FOR LOCALHOST
        'PORT': '3307', #Empty by default
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 7, Python 3.4 (I heard was not compatible with install MySQL-python so instead I downloaded mysqlclient 1.3.6).

When I ran `easy_install mysql-python`  it results in

```
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe'
failed with exit status 2
```

Similarly it asks for config-win.h when running `pip install mysql-python`, along with a scary error

```
Command "D:\Users\Python\python.EXE -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-build-w7q9kjxi\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('
\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u982sugf-record\install-record.t
xt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build
-w7q9kjxi\mysql-python
```

I'm pretty confused about this. The tutorial I've been looking at strays from me here, and I have no idea what to do with a WHL of mysqlclient.

Things I've tried already:

- `easy_install Distribute` works but does not change anything
- `python manage.py syncdb` no module named 'MySQLdb'
- `apt-get install python-mysqldb` term 'apt-get' not recognized at all.

Please help with this beginner question, thanks for your time, if more info is needed I'd be happy to provide.

Comment: What version of Django?

Comment: I think 1.8.1 from recently

Comment: You're clearly looking at some out-of-date resources. You almost never want to use `easy_install`. And you _definitely_ don't want `distribute`; that's an obsolete project that has been replaced by `setuptools`.

Comment: Anyway, your actual problem smells like the `vcvarsall` problem configuring Python to use Visual Studio; do a search for `[python] vcvarsall` and you should find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Visual Studio, you'll need a [binary installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) for the right Python version and architecture. The easiest is probably to get both 32- and 64- bit packages for the installed Python version and install them both.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but if I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in a different directory can it use that? I'll try the binary hang on.

Comment: Yes, as long as the right environment variables are set (https://methedrine.org/2014/11/19/using-setuptools-with-the-microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-2-7/comment-page-1/) , the Python installer should find the compiler.

Comment: I have `mysqlclient-1.3.6-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl` and now `MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` in my Python directory let me rerun pip

Comment: It should be either that one or the win32 one, yes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything and that may be some stupid mistake on my part. Did I put it in the right place? dir "D:/Users/Python"

Comment: I think you have to run the installer package by double-clicking it after you download it. Just putting it in the Python folder won't do anything I'm afraid.

Comment: Not ignoring you or abarnert, just taking forever to deal with running it with pip install. It's having a cry about my OS being 32 bit but it's really 64 so in trying to install the wheels when they're giving me this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format

Comment: It has worked `PS D:\users\python> pip install mysql-python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in d:\users\` but for some reason or another `python manage.py syncdb` throws a different error about DLL %1 is not a valid Win32 app. Sounds like a question for another day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error working on Windows, I solved it by downloading apart and then copying the`MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info` and the `MySQLdb` folders and the `_mysql.pyd` and `_mysql_exceptions.py` files in `C:\Users\%The-path-of-your-project%\Lib\site-packages`