# Seaborn won't import - python 2.7 - pip install

Tags: python, pip, dllimport, seaborn, dllnotfoundexception

I did

```
pip install seaborn
```

Then in my file I have the following

```
import seaborn as sns
```

but it gives the following error

```
 line 10, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import palettes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 338, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 627, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What have I done wrong?

***Background***
I have scipy and statsmodels installed.

I wrote a program in anaconda and that worked fine but I need it to work in regular python 2.7 as I need the BBG plugin which isn't possible with anaconda. So using the anaconda environment is not an option.

Finally the rest of the program works fine it just won't let me overlay styles on my charts as seaborn won't import.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug inside the package to me. Maybe get in contact with upstream author.

Comment: I am quite new so when you say get in contact with them how was I go about that?

Comment: try the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596125/python-dll-load-failed