# ERROR :import seaborn- while running the program : from ._ufuncs import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, seaborn

I am using Window 10 64-bit
Python version :

Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I have installed scipy :

---

```
C:\Users\Aswathi>pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==0.19.1 from file:///C:/Users/Aswathi/scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in c:\users\aswathi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\users\aswathi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from scipy==0.19.1)
```

---

But I am still facing error on Pycharm for import seaborn

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aswathi/Desktop/Analytics in Python - Edx/game_of_thrones_battle_dataset.py", line 3, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 348, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 175, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Users\Aswathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After initially looking for seaborn answers I realised it relates to scipy problems (ufuncs), which reveals many potential answers.

This question: [PYTHON DLL load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596125/python-dll-load-failed) solved the problem for me

I installed the relevant numpy+mkl from the wonderful [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)