# Seaborn import error

Tags: python, dll, seaborn

I have been trying to import Seaborn in Python 3.6 but I always get an error:
 `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I tried to install 2 DLLs (`msvcp71` and `msvcr71`) but that did not help. I am using Windows 10.

The full error is:
    import seaborn

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 343, in <module>
    from .stats import *

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 169, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR :import seaborn- while running the program : from .\_ufuncs import \* ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306266/error-import-seaborn-while-running-the-program-from-ufuncs-import-import)

Comment: Those solutions don't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Scipy so I uninstalled (pip uninstall) it and then reinstalled Scipy. Also reinstalled seaborn. That worked.

Trying to install from .whl didn't work but pip worked.