# Command line issue: whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, command-line

I am having issues installing [GraphLab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GraphLab-Create) in Python 2.7. I downloaded the whl file and have the following line in my command prompt: `C:\Python27> pip install GraphLab_Create-1.6.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`. However, I get the error `GraphLab_Create-1.6.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. I looked at similar issues other people had posted but am unable to find it useful for this particular situation. Any help solving this issue would be great.

And `echo %PATH%` returns a line containing `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

**Edit**: I was using Python 3.4 as default, but changed my environment variables so that I am now using Python 2.7 as default. Could this be a possible issue?

Comment: Just to make sure. Did you try this solution? [Rename part of file with win_amd64 and replace with win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format)

Comment: @idjaw I did try that but to no avail.