# Installing scipy from wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to install

```
scipy-0.16.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I got the error:

```
scipy-0.16.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Following the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format), I've tried changing 'win_amd64' to 'win32' (which doesn't work) and to 'any'. After changing the file name and running

```
pip install scipy-0.16.1-cp33-none-any.whl
```

I get:

```
Unpacking C:\python33\scipy-0.16.1-cp33-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy
Cleaning up...
```

However, scipy doesn't seem to be installed anywhere. Running python and trying

```
>>> import scipy
```

gives an error. I'm very confused and would appreciate help.

Comment: Are you sure that when you run `python` you are getting the same version of Python as the one that `pip` is installing for?

Comment: That's it, thanks! I was doing all this in C:\Python33 but pip was installing it in C:\Python34