# Windows 10 installed NumPy from a wheel: "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, numpy, windows-10, command-prompt

I installed Python and `pip` on my Windows 10 machine (it's a [Lenovo Yoga 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_Yoga#Lenovo_Yoga_3)).

`pip install numpy` generated errors, but I successfully installed it from a wheel.

> *[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)*

This included a trick found at this question: *[Cannot install NumPy from a wheel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format)*

Next I try using NumPy, and it doesn't find anything:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\J\Downloads>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\J\Downloads>py -2
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

This may not be specific to Python, but I have not figured it out yet.  For work purposes, I have a dual-boot partition: Windows 10 and [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet).

*[ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)*

Comment: are you sure you didn't install a 64-bit wheel?

Comment: @PaulH I installed a 64-bit wheel and renamed it... How do I tell if I am running 32-bit or 64-bit windows?

Comment: You're most likely on 64-bit windows, but that doesn't matter. What matters is that you're on 32-bit python, so all of your third party extensions need to be the 32-bit versions as well.

Comment: @PaulH it's very early on -- I just got this computer two weeks ago.  I would wipe out Python and try again https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/

Comment: if it were my machine, I'd wipe out whatever you've installed and just use conda http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Comment: If you want a nice, modern,  scientific and plug and play package, I suggest you http://www.pyzo.org/ .

Answer (score 1):

Your Python interpreter is 32 bit and most probably you installed a 64 bit version of NumPy. If your Windows is 64 bit, I advise that you remove Python and install a 64 bit Python and install libraries needed again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for Python 3.6, `pip install numpy` (on Windows 10).

I managed to finally solve it by installing from binary here:

[Enter link description here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/02/25/install-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-python-3-windows/)

I found the previous link in this guide:

[This guide...](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)