# Can get PyQt4 to work under python 3.4, but not 3.5

Tags: python, pyqt4

When I use python 3.4, everything works fine but when I use 3.5 I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'
```

I have installed the binding wheel file for 3.4, 
PyQt4-4.11.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl, and everything went smoothly there but when I try to do the same for 3.5 I get the message saying this wheel is not supported on this platform.

Anyone know where I may be going wrong?

Comment: What **specific** pyqt4 package did you try to install for python-3.5, and where did you get it from?

Comment: PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl    from the Gohlke website

Comment: I have actually got everything to work in 3.4 so it's ok. I was just wondering why it wasn't working for 3.5.

Comment: Is your python-3.5 64-bit or 32-bit? Obviously the pyqt package needs to be compatible with python (or vice versa).

Comment: Yeah, both pythons and my computer are 64-bit. I even tried installing the 32-bit version of that wheel just to see if that would work but came back with the same error message.

Comment: Try the hack in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28111899/984421).