# "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python, numpy, module, pip, pyopengl

I saw the same question, but it didn't work for me.

```
pip install PyOpenGL.3.1.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

I also have the same problem for [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy):

```
pip install numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

Then I get:

> numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
> this platform. Storing debug log for failure in
> C://Users/myUsername/pip/pip.log

I'm using 64-bit and Python 3.4.0. What is wrong?

Comment: I think for me at least the issue is 32 bit Python. Pytorch only works with 64 bit Python

Comment: Answered in this post for M1 Users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693640/8291933

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try updating pip first before you rename `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: In my case it is not working. Can you elaborate why it should help?

Comment: Because pip needs to update to learn new versions. It doesn't automatically know what your python version is capable of.

Answer (score 24):

1. Check the supported tags for wheel version for your system(platform).
2. To check supported tag run the following command `pip debug --verbose`
3. When you run the command, you will get many lists, along with supported tags, download compatible wheel file from supported tags.
4. install wheel file using this command `pip install pycurl-7.43.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Supported tags portion looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I was installing Pillow.  The normal  pip install Pillow didn't work (on windows), it wanted to build it from source, I found some Pillow .whl files but chose the wrong one.  This helped me find the right one (pip on windows should do this for me!!!)

Comment: This is the best solution that i've found here. I think it should mark as the [Best Solution].

Answer (score 8):

You'll probably have to rename your .whl file like `numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl` before installing. Your `pip` has a finite number of tags it recognizes in wheel filenames.

See this answer for more on this: *[Cannot install numpy from wheel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format/28111899#28111899)*

Comment: Same thing applies for Pyopengl and all wheel packages.

Comment: I'm having the same problem only with Python 2.7, and renaming is not working.

Comment: How did you rename it ? What's the new name you set ?

Comment: I renamed it with the same formula, with `none` instead of the second cp27 tag.

Comment: you should really open a python shell and check the output of : `import pip; print pip.pep425tags.get_supported()` (Copy-paste the result here). Moreover, is your python installation a 64-bit installation ?

Comment: Starting with Python 3.8 and pip 19.2.3 on Windows there is no "m" at the end of the second `cp38` tag.  The correct wheel name is `numpy-1.17.1+mkl-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`.  See [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6885) and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue36707).

Comment: Starting with pip 10 and later, `pip.pep425tags` has been moved to `pip._internal.pep425tags`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248524/module-pip-has-no-attribute-pep425tags).

Comment: I have tried like this it worked for me too!! 

C:\Users\Python\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\Downloads\Cython-0.28-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl

Cython-0.28-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

C:\Users\Python\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\Downloads\Cython-0.28-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

Processing c:\users\downloads\cython-0.28-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: Cython
Successfully installed Cython-0.28

Comment: Posting for redundancy you can use `pip debug --verbose` to get the tags as well.

You need to rename *after* the version of the package name in the file...that it works this way is wild...

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to consider

Python versions should match, OS should be 64 bit and python should also be 64 bit.

And as in your case both of these conditions are met, you have to make sure that **pip** is able to handle all the fields in wheel file name.

For example in my case my pip was not handling **"cp35m"**

To ensure, in python shell

> > import pip

Then type

> > pip.pep425tags.get_supported()

you should be able to see all the fields your **pip** command can handle. If any one is missing try updating Pip first.

However in my case even updating was giving error. So I uninstalled **python 3.5.1** and installed **python 3.5.2**, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check for:

1. Even though I my system is 64 I had 32 python installed. You can check this by opening your IDLE.
2. I had python 2 and 3 installed so updating pip was updating the wrong python for me. And of course I just wasn't trying to install the right kind of package because it was the wrong python version in the path.
3. If you are still having some problems like me where doing pip2 or pip3 fixes didn't seem to work, I did a quick fix. My pip only had python 3 in its path, so I went to systems>advanced system settings>environment variables and then added "C:\Python27\Scripts\" to the `PATH` variable. This solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

First check which version of the interpreter, 32-bit or 64-bit. Type `python` and you will get it. Mine is 64 bit.

Next, check if your wheel file is for 64 bit or 32 bit. Compare it with your Python bitness to see if it is the same or not.

If there is still an error coming, check your file location in [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) and compare it with where you have saved your file.

Save the file in the cmd location, for example, *C:\Users*, and you get the result successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but I ran into this error recently. At one point I created a folder with several prerequisite .whl files and added "prereq - 1 - ", "prereq - 2 - ", etc. to the beginnings of the filenames to help others/myself in the future know which order to install them in (I work in an offline environment).

I would get the "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform" error when trying to `py -m pip install "filename.whl" --no-index`. When I removed the filename "prefix" that I added, it worked.

Just wanted to throw this out there in case anyone else runs into this issue after editing the name of a .whl file.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have Python 64 bit install.
You can download it here and the 64bit version is at the bottom of the page: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/