# Installing lxml for Python3.4 on Windows

Tags: windows, lxml, python-3.4

Since I am having trouble getting pip to recognize Proxy Server from behind a corporate firewall, I am getting to install the unofficial Windows Binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

[image: Shot from my cmd]

Both lxml-3.7.3-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64 and lxml-3.7.3-cp34-cp34m-win32 gives me the error

> is not a supported wheel on this platform. Storing debug log for
>   failure in C:\Users\sjacob\pip\pip.log

What do I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip first before your installation:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

(As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401077/7596140))