# cmappertools problems installing

Tags: visual-studio, package, installation

I'm trying to install cmappertools via pip install in Anaconda on Windows. After installling Visual Studio an running `pip install cmappertools` I got:

```
Collecting cmappertools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/38/f913b01b6a77fb89fe2b2a7482d19c5bd3153c32c7fb563f4cefc884602f/cmappertools-1.0.24.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cmappertools
  Building wheel for cmappertools (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\Astrid\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Astrid\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vk7bp3mb\\cmappertools\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Astrid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xopgv228' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Version: 1.0.24
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'cmappertools' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe 
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Users\Astrid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include 
-IC:\Users\Astrid\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Astrid\Anaconda3\include "
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcmappertools.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cmappertools.obj /EHsc
  cmappertools.cpp
  cmappertools.cpp(31): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 
'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' 
failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer can help to resolve this issue, if it helps you can consider marking it as answer. And if that still blocks you, please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time before. It didn't work but it's because my pip only handle "cp37m" and not older versions, and cmappertools don't have that version

Comment: Yeah, the latest is `cp37m` :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another way to install the library, 
we can find the cmappertools's wheel file [here](https://pypi.org/project/cmappertools/#files).

Download the one suitable for you and use command like `pip install "path\xx.whl"` can help resolve this issue.

**In addition:** If you meet error message like `xxx.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`, update pip first using `pip install --upgrade pip`,then use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46265902/10910450) to find the correct version for you.