# cmappertools installation failed

Tags: python, c++, windows, package, installation

I am trying to install cmappertools using `pip install cmappertools` but it is failing while giving the following error:

```
   command: 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4hb985an\\cmappertools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\s114819\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4hb985an\\cmappertools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x55seam8' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hb985an\cmappertools\
  Complete output (12 lines):
  Version: 1.0.24
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'cmappertools' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\s114819\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\s114819\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\include -IC:\Users\s114819\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcmappertools.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cmappertools.obj /EHsc
  cmappertools.cpp
  cmappertools.cpp(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmappertools
```

I have tried installation using the wheel file for cmappertools as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565601/cmappertools-problems-installing) but again I get the same error. 
I got the Boost libraries from [boost.org](https://www.boost.org/) extracted the files and after running

```
bootstrap
./b2
```

I copied and pasted all the files in the `boost_1_72_0` directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx86\x64`. However I am still getting the same error. It seems like boost libraries are not properly linked. Can someone help to fix this error?

Comment: First of all, do **not** copy external files, libraries, etc into the compile tree. That could cause all sorts of crazy unexpected things to happen or fail. You simply need to tell the tools where to find the library. But why don't you just install the prebuilt binaries and avoid these problems? There's a [wheel for cmapper for Windows](https://pypi.org/project/cmappertools/#files).

Comment: I did `pip install cmappertools-1.0.24-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` but it gave the error `ERROR: cmappertools-1.0.24-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`  which I assume is due to python version mismatch since I am running python 3.7.6. Is there a prebuilt for this version?

Comment: It looks like 3.6 is the most recent in that list, so I guess not. You could always install Python 3.6 in parallel.