# Installing pyodbc and unixodbc on a mac

Tags: macos, pyodbc, apple-m1, unixodbc

I've seen [Pypyodbc: Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found") error when trying to connect to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566121/pypyodbc-cant-open-lib-freetds-file-not-found-error-when-trying-to-conne), but. that's 7 years old, and doesn't seem to be working for me, possibly because brew appears to be putting things in different places now?

I've used brew to install unixodbc, it's in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`.

When I do pip install pyodbc, it appears to work, but I get:

```
 connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

which is obviously wrong, because libtdsodbc is in `/opt/homebrew/lib`

I tried editing `odbcinst.ini`, but I'm not sure where that's supposed to live. There wasn't one in /etc, or a /etc/unixODBC directory... and when I create either one, the don't seem to be read, because it still complains about /usr/local/lib...

ETA: This is on a new Macbook, so on one of the new M1 chips.

Comment: Why the close?  the 7 year old question didn't solve my problem. Is there a way I can improve the question?

Comment: Answered the question in the below post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693640/8291933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This is a BAD answer in the hopes of attracting a good one, but it technically seems to be working.

Homebrew for M1 installs everything in `/opt/homebrew`. Everything else expects things in `/usr/local`. On a new computer, `/usr/local/lib` didn't even exist. So I did

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib /usr/local/lib
```

**THIS IS VERY BAD AND I KNOW IT** But it's the only way I've figured out currently to deal with the problem. Maybe something hasn't caught up to M1? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

BETTER solution:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Comment: Somehow this STOPPED WORKING? it's no longer looking at DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH? It's just looking straight to /usr/local/lib? (I set DYLD_.... to empty and it still looks in usr/local/lib...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request that has been pretty much ignored for 13 months now by the pyodbc maintainer: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/870

You can install the forked version with this command (might need to uninstall the previous version or add extra arguments to force reinstall)

```
python3 -m pip install git+git://github.com/Aloisius/pyodbc.git@m1-homebrew
```