# Install numpy from a wheel package on Redhat 6.5

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am trying to install numpy from a wheel package (that I have generated in my virtualenv) on a Redhat 6.5 with python version =2.6.6:

```
pip install numpy-1.11.1-cp26-cp26mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I am getting the following error:

```
numpy-1.11.1-cp26-cp26mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Any way to fix that? thanks :)

Comment: Is your pip up to date? You can update it with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Simon Visser on question : 
[Cannot install numpy from wheel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format?rq=1)
the solution is to replace "cp26mu" in the name of the file by none.