# Dysfunctioning of pip in installing python packages on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, pip, arcgis, pyproj

I am trying to install a Python module - pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl using the Python package installer - pip. Since I use a version of Python 2.7.10, which comes bundled with ArcGIS 10.4.1, it is already preloaded with pip, as all versions 2.7.9 onwards are. To install the module, I opened the Command Prompt in the directory of the module and typed

```
pip install pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32
```

to get the error, which I have written below:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32 (from versions:) No matching distribution found for pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32
```

Comment: Try `pip install pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` if you have the `.whl` file locally.

Comment: I am getting the error: pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: The `cp27` means CPython 2.7 and you said you are using Python 2.7 so that should be ok. Are you maybe using 64 bit Windows (`win32`)?

Comment: Yes, but how do I fix the problem?

Comment: You need to find the `pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win64.whl` file, a `win32` Python wheel file can't be used on `win64`. Usually both are provided in a project, if not you need to ask the person who generated the wheel.

Comment: I cannot send you a snapshot of the error I am getting since I do not have the rights to post an image. However, I have downloaded pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl and entered: pip install pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl to the same error as above. Could I email you the screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure from here. You may want to review the steps followed in this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ArcGIS 10.4 comes bundled with Python 2.7.10, it is pre-installed with pip. Pip is a recursive acronym that stands for "pip installs packages" and is a package management system that is used to install software packages written in Python, which is pre-installed in Python version 2.7.9+. Therefore, to install pyproj, make sure that `%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\` and `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4` are added in the Path of Environmental Variables in System Properties. After that, run Command Prompt as an administrator and type `pip install pyproj` to install pyproj.