# Installing PyQt4 on python 3.7. getting error

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to install PyQt4 on python 3.7.

I get this error:

```
ERROR: PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I downloaded the PyQt4 on my computer, and basically just follow  this:

```
pip install "c:\doc\PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install numpy from wheel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format)

Comment: @pedramghaderi Try using PyQt5 . Did you use `pip install pyqt4` to install module ?