# Error when installing mpi4py

Tags: python, macos, installation, mpi

I'm trying to install mpi4py using pip install mpi4py, but I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Cannot find 'mpi.h' header. Check your configuration!!!
```

Earlier in the same error report I have,

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
```

What might the problem be?

Thanks!

Comment: What commands do you execute? Do you have MPI installed?

Comment: what is os x-specific about this?

Answer (score 59):

As the error says, there are libraries missing. I solved it by installing libopenmpi-dev package

```
sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev
```

and then installed the mpi4py using pip

```
pip install mpi4py
```

Comment: Note that this question was tagged osx and apt implies debian/ubuntu/related variants (but not saying this answer is bad)

Comment: Please don't do `sudo pip install XXX`

Comment: I am in a machine without sudo permissions. Yet I have conda.
In that case, @9Dragons' answer solves it.

`conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py mpich`

Answer (score 40):

I met with the similar problem and fixed this by firstly

```
brew install mpich
```

And then

```
pip install mpi4py
```

Answer (score 13):

you can do this:

```
brew install mpich
```

then

```
sudo find / -name mpicc
```

finally

```
env MPICC=/yourpath/mpicc pip3 install mpi4py
```

Comment: The second step was not necessary in my case.

Answer (score 12):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I just use the conda install:

```
brew install mpich
```

```
conda install mpi4py
```

Answer (score 6):

If mpi4py cannot find mpi.h, then likely the problem is how you are pointing mpi4py to your existing mpi library.

```
$ python setup.py build --mpicc=/where/you/have/mpicc
```

Now, there there are a few special cases related to OS X.  You should consult http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html to see if any apply to you.

Comment: if you want to use pip, you can do: `env MPICC=/path/to/mpicc/ pip install mpi4py`

Answer (score 4):

in my case, all solutions above is failed but succeded by conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py mpich
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody stumbles by and has the same problem I had:

I wanted to install mpi4py using pip as root:

```
sudo pip install mpi4py
```

I got the error message that `mpi.h` was missing during the installation. The path was set correctly, but only for my user, not for root. So if you run into trouble with missing libraries/headers during any installation, make sure the correct environment is also set up for root.

As I use `mpi-selector` to select which mpi implementation you use, I just had to run `mpi-selector` as root to set up everything correctly, and the installation succeeded.

Comment: `mpi.h` is a header file and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for libraries. The issue was more likely with your `$PATH` (e.g. `mpicc` and friends were not in your default path)

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue, the following helps me as well.

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help on Fedora 38:

```
sudo dnf install python3-mpi4py-mpich python3-mpi4py-openmpi # second one not necessary I guess
module load mpi/mpich-$(arch)
pip3 install mpi4py
```

Mentioned here = https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html2

Answer (score -4):

first post here and new to python , sorry if im off topic.

i finally installed  mpi4py

1) by downloading the right version from here    https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py

2) open cmd  ,change directory to where the downloaded file is

3) pip install some-package.whl     ( [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) )

Comment: Hi @Frikg, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Indeed, your answer doesn't seem to be addressing the specific problem that the original poster had, and seems offtopic!

Comment: hi @frandroid , you are right .  I 've been searching for days  to install it so i hope that someone who has the same issue with me will come across with my answer 
(title helps to easy find this post) :)