# Installing mpi4py on mac

Tags: python, mpi

When trying to install mpi4py on mac I get the error

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

and also

```
      #include <mpi.h>
               ^~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
```

I have seen some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440834/error-when-installing-mpi4py) to this but none of the answers seem to work on mac e.g.
`sudo apt-get install lipopenmpi-dev` results in `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: You'll first want to install MPI. Try with Homebrew, one of the (non-Apple) macOS package managers. You'll also need a compatible compiler, which probably means installing gcc through Homebrew.

Comment: An alternative to try is with Conda. I'm not sure, but it is possible that Conda (or Mamba) will install gcc, MPI and mpi4py for you in one environment.

Comment: `mpi4py` is built on top of `mpi`, so you should have one library installed. that being said, make your life easy and use a package manager such as `homebrew` or a `conda` variant.

Comment: How do I install both mpi and a compiler with homebrew? Sorry I'm pretty new to this!

Comment: https://brew.sh/ for getting Homebrew to work.

Comment: However, if you're all new to this, it is much better to find a local person that has (good) experience with installing such software on a mac than asking the internet. Of course, if you're the only person, or the only person with a mac, then the internet is probably the next best option.

Comment: The reason for saying that is that you may get multiple pieces of advice, and at some point you'll have a virtual-env in a Conda environment using Homebrew MPI (speaking from experience), as a result of multiple failed attempts, and which at some point results in a chaos, and it may be hard to restore that. Better to have one definite working result from someone who can look over your shoulder.

Comment: For compiler; you need to install Xcode from AppStore, not from homebrew ..  Also worth pointing out; homebrew does ship mpi4py package directly ..

Comment: simply `brew install mpi4py` and you won't even have to build a MPI library.

Comment: @9769953 unfortunately I am all alone in this so all advice is welcome. I'm pretty versed in python but just trying to parallelise and have borrowed some code to test mpi4py for this.

Comment: Thing is, this is not about Python, but about basically sys-admin work for macOS. But I might make an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Are you also going to want OpenMP? They often go hand in hand when installing, but OpenMP is an annoying beast on macOS, since you'll need to use a compatible compiler.

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install --no-deps mpi4py --upgrade`

Comment: @toyotaSupra macOS has no `py` executable; as far as I'm aware, that's a Windows thing. Also, how would it help to upgrade mpi4py, leaving out the dependencies? With or without dependencies, the MPI libraries won't be there. And if the OP tried a recent installation (likely), mpi4py is already at the latest release, and `--upgrade` does effectively nothing. I find your comment confusing.

Comment: Try this on brew `$ brew install mpi4py`

Answer (score 0):

For `mpi4py` to work, you'll need the MPI libraries. On a Debian-style Linux machine, that could indeed be something like `sudo apt-get lipopenmpi-dev`, but not on macOS.

You can try installing it within a Conda environment. I prefer Homebrew, and this normally works fine on a system that is used by just one person (exceptions could be when you have multiple projects that require conflicting versions of MPI, like version 3.x, 4.x or 5.0). Homebrew also has tons of other useful packages (but so does Conda).

Install Homebrew from https://brew.sh/ , and follow the instruction to get set up. You should only need `sudo` once, to create the `/opt/homebrew` or whatever directory in `/` you prefer (just stay out of any existing system directories).

Search for e.g. open-MPI with `brew search mpi`, and then `brew info open-mpi` once you've found the likely package name (there is `mpich` as well, for example). Now install it: `brew install open-mpi` (no sudo needed). Which is also shown in the MPI manual: https://docs.open-mpi.org/en/v5.0.x/installing-open-mpi/quickstart.html .

Note that this will install version 5.0 (and update it over time, as long you as run Homebrew updates).

You may need to point mpi4py to where your open-MPI installation is. To find the files, do `brew list open-mpi`. You'll find that the `mpicc` wrappe is at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.1/bin/mpicc` (at least mine is); following [the MPI4py installation manual](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html), you can run

```
env MPICC=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.1/bin/mpicc python -m pip install mpi4py
```

Which should work for the regular system Python, any manually installed Python, or within a virtual-env, or even within a Conda environment (though in the latter case, you'd obviously want to try and install mpi4py through Conda, which then also should install its own open-mpi library).

---

As noted in the comments, you can also simply use Homebrew to install MPI4py directly:

```
brew install mpi4py
```

This, however, will use Homebrew's Python (3.12 currently). Which may or may not be a good thing, but if you want to use another Python version, this option likely won't work (the normal Homebrew open-mpi will work with any Python, since it's not a Python package).

---

Conda will be a lot simpler, in a way. Assuming you use [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/), you could create an environment with a suitable Python and MPI4py with just

```
conda create -n mympi4py mpi4py python=3.9
```

Pick your favourite Python version; Conda will install it; it will also install the required MPI libraries, and match mpi4py with it. And then activate your Conda environment to use it all: `conda activate mympi4py`.

The reason I don't like it, is that I've seen too many circumstances where it got installed in the base environment, or mixed up with other libraries installed on the machine. Plus Conda has an annoying habit of putting a bunch of stuff in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`; mostly for convenience, so it's my personal distaste, as this doesn't seem needed).

Perhaps that won't be the case here. In fact, when done right, a Conda solution and a Homebrew solution can co-exist as two entirely independent solutions. So perhaps using Conda is worth a try.