# Installing Python Package .whl from a specific directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to install the Python package numpy from the a .whl file. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885547/2327821) provides the syntax for using pip/wheel to install a package:

```
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/where/its/downloaded package_name
```

So after [downloading](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) the .whl file and renaming it `numpy.whl` I followed this syntax accordingly:

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=C:\Users\User Name\Downloads numpy
```

When I do this I get

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 305, in run

    name, None, isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 181, in from
_line
    isolated=isolated)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 54, in __ini
t__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 2873, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 2820, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 2785, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'Name\\Downloads', 'at', '\\Downloads
')
```

I downloaded the `numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl` file and am running Python 2.7 on 64bit architecture so I don't think the version I downloaded is the problem. The other issue I can think of is that the syntax in the original answer is written linux and I cannot find an example that deals with Windows directories. The other issue could be that my `User Name` is two words with a space in it that Wheel is not set up to handle. I tried adding `/` in front of the space in case that was the problem, but no dice. How can I install a Python package on Windows using a .whl file?

Comment: Don't rename with wheel file.

Comment: Install with: `pip install numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: That works if I add the .whl file to the `C:\Python27\Scripts\ ` so immediate problem solved, but ideally you should be able to run pip in the scripts folder, but have the .whl file in a download folder (which is what I was trying to do above).

Comment: No, you can do it anywhere if you navigate the command prompt to the directory containing the wheel, for example: `cd C:\Users\Michael\Downloads`

Comment: And it will install the package into the correct directory for Python 2.7 (or the relevant version)?

Comment: Yes, how that going for you?