# Updating skeletons in pycharm and kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

I want to use kivy in pycharm. After I add python.bat in "Project Interpreter", it takes about 20 min to Update skeletons. Everything is ok till here but after I close `pycharm` and open again, `pycharm` wants to update skeletons again forcing me to wait for 20 min everytime.
What should I do?

Comment: Have the same problem here. Unable to fix it so far. (Win 7)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative install with skeleton updates completing in under a minute. Rather than using the recommended [kivy.zip portable archive install](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html), install kivy in the usual way on a virtual environment:

1. Ensure you have the latest version of Pip (e.g. `pip install --upgrade pip`)
2. [Install virtual env](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) if you haven't already
3. Create a virtual env home directory on your PC: (e.g. type a name for it such as "`.venv.`")
4. Create a subdirectory for Kivy virtual environments (`\.venv\kivy`)
5. `cd` into your virtual enviroment home directory: `cd C:\somewhere\.venv\kivy`
6. [create a virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html): `virtualenv venv`
7. Activate your virtual environment: `venv\scripts\activate.bat`
8. [Download the latest kivy wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy) into your current directory
9. [Install the wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file#answer-27885547) of Kivy: `pip install --use-wheel Kivy-1.9.0-cp27-none-win32.whl`
10. Add `\.venv\kivy\venv\Scripts\python.exe` as the [interpreter for your pycharm project](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's#setting-up-kivy-with-pycharm-4-on-windows)