# Error installing Willie irc bot for Python

Tags: python

Trying to install this Python IRC bot called Willie. This is what happens when I run setup.py:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.1\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_setup_runner.py" C:\Users\Quibbles\Documents\willie-5.3.0\setup.py
Testing started at 1:35 PM ...
running pycharm_test
Searching for pygeoip
Best match: pygeoip 0.3.2
Processing pygeoip-0.3.2-py3.4.egg

Using c:\users\quibbles\documents\willie-5.3.0\.eggs\pygeoip-0.3.2-py3.4.egg
Searching for pyenchant
Best match: pyenchant 1.6.6
Processing pyenchant-1.6.6-py3.4-win32.egg

Using c:\users\quibbles\documents\willie-5.3.0\.eggs\pyenchant-1.6.6-py3.4-win32.egg
Searching for praw
Best match: praw 2.1.21
Processing praw-2.1.21-py3.4.egg

Using c:\users\quibbles\documents\willie-5.3.0\.eggs\praw-2.1.21-py3.4.egg
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.4.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.4.4.tar.gz#md5=a9a65972afc173ec7a39c585f4eea69c
Processing lxml-3.4.4.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\Quibbles\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-p_x9naya\lxml-3.4.4\setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.4.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\Quibbles\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-p_x9naya\lxml-3.4.4\egg-dist-tmp-0expfysa
Building lxml version 3.4.4.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt 
C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
lxml.etree.c
C:\Users\Quibbles\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-p_x9naya\lxml-3.4.4\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/embolalia/willie/releases/tag/v5.3.0 and tried running setup.py in PyCharm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'L'I's answer gives you a hint of where to start searching next, but isn't a useful answer.

After several attempts on my own, I found that to get the lxml library installed, I needed to do the following:

First, download the lxml library from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This is necessary because the PiPy archives (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4) are way out of date, only giving you the option to install for Python 3.2 for the 3+ series, which of course is useless if you're on 3.4. There's also issues if you're using 64-bit. They may be sufficient if you're using 2.7, though.

Then use the instructions here: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)  to install the .whl file.

However that only fixes half the problem.  The willie package appears to be broken in other ways (on Windows) because of trying to reference a unix-like /tmp directory (absolute path) instead of the proper Windows Temp directory.

This issue describes the problem, though no fix has yet been made: https://github.com/embolalia/willie/issues/811

It indicates that it's a Windows-specific bug in the installer.  To work around *that*, download the .tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/willie/5.3.0

Unpack it.  Go to the willie-5.3.0\willie.egg-info directory, and edit the SOURCES.txt file.  The fifth line is `/tmp/tmpeAhjCF/willie`.  Delete that line.

Repackage the directory into a .tar.gz archive.  Install via `pip install .\willie-5.3.0.tar.gz`.

Now it's installed, and you're ready for the next round of problems of actually getting it to *run* on Windows.  Since I haven't actually succeeded in doing that yet, that's as far as I can help for right now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly obvious by the error messages:

> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

**You need to have the dev libxml2 and libxslt installed.** It appears either you have the wrong versions perhaps, or don't have them installed properly.