# Why I can't import Pyqt in python after install it?

Tags: python, pyqt, installation, python-wheel

I am very noob in Python and now I have a hard time to install PyQt and PyQwt.

I searched how to do for many site but I still can't get out of this problem.
Now I decide to follow [Christoph Gohlke's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
I'm success to use pip to install numpy wheel file and can import it in python but it is not for PyQt and PyQwt.

For PyQt, when I install the wheel file through cmd with this

```
pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

it appear

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyQt4==4.11.4 from file:///C:/Users/Mann/Downloads/PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

I think the installation probably success, so I try to import PyQt4 in Python2.7

```
import PyQt4
```

but it fail and appear an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyQt4
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I also call pip.exe in "Script" directory as https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/5041101 said but it still the same.
Please help me get out of this.

Thank you

Comment: What is exact package name that can be found in _c:\python27\lib\site-packages_ ? is it **PyQt4**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try forcing re-installation?

```
pip install --force-reinstall PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If you not enlighten me how to do, I would continued in a hard time.