# OpenCV3 installation with Python3.4 on Windows 8.1 (64 bits)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, 64-bit, opencv3.0

I have successfully installed the *64* bit version of *Python 3.4.3* on my *Intel* based core *i7* machine which is running *Windows 8.1*.  I have also successfully installed the *64* bit version of *numpy* and run the `numpy.test()` and things look fine. I have installed/extracted *opencv3.0 *and have copied the file `cv2.pyd`  (from *lib/opencv/build/python/2.7/x64*) to *python/Lib/site-packages*. When I run `print (sys.path)`, it correctly finds the *C:\Python34\lib\site-packages* where `cv2.pyd` resides. I have two concerns:

(i) Why the folder is called *2.7*? I read many article here that *opencv3* can run with *python 3.x*

(ii) Why the file is still called `cv2.pyd` and not `cv3`?

Either way when I `import cv2` I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have read many similar Q&As here for similar situations but not exactly for my setup.  Any help or suggestions are appreciated. But please do not say uninstall everything and re-install *32* bits -- I need the *64*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question should answer most of your questions: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

cv2 is just a newer API version of python wrapper of opencv C++ library. So cv2 is what we need to install and there is no cv3. But the official installer may not have python34 build for cv2.pyd. so either build it from source or use Gohlke's whl package (recommended!!).

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you install manually or from Gohlke's whl package, I found the need to create/edit the file cv.py in site_packages as follows:

```
import cv2 as cv
```