# pyenchant installation on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyenchant

I am trying to install pyenchant on Mac OS X Yosemite. It works fine on linux machines but not in mac, I am having the following error:

> ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.

This is how I installed the package:

```
pip install pyenchant
```

and next, I import it in this way:

```
import enchant
```

I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: And have you *"install[ed] it via your OS package manager, or use[d] a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI"*?

Comment: I installed the package using the pip command, that's all what I did.

Comment: If that's all you've done, **why?!** Have you read e.g. https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html?

Comment: I have put the source distribution inside the enchant installation as well. Is there anything that I missed. I have read the manual multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean *"put the source distribution inside"*? That's not the same as installation. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Comment: Here is what I did: `pip install pyenchant`. I downloaded pyenchant source distribution. I unzipped it. when I ran, `python setup.py install' I am having the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90814/discussion-between-user2161903-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: No, I'm good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enchant is a C library, and pyenchant provides Python bindings to that library.
For your code to work, you need to install Enchant as well.
If you're using homebrew, you can use:

```
>>brew install enchant
```

After installing Enchant, you can then install Pyenchant:

```
>>pip install pyenchant
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `brew install enchant` or `brew install pyenchant`? I installed it using `pip`, is `brew` going to make any difference?

Comment: Enchant and pyenchat are two different projects. Enchant is the generic interface into various existing spell checking libaries. (https://github.com/AbiWord/enchant) Pyenchant provides a set of Python language bindings for the Enchant spellchecking library.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your **Xcode is updated**.  If it is not updated, you will get an error when running the brew installer:
`configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.`