# How to install shapely (python package)

Tags: python, shapely

The instructions for Windows ask to download the installer from
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

The link for my version displays as "Shapely‑1.5.13‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl".

However it is actually a zip file, which contains 2 folders, neither of which appear to contain a .whl file or an installer.

Note that the question is not about how to install a .whl file, but why I can't see a .whl file.

How do I install this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install this normally using pip?

Comment: The instructions (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) mention that the installer is required for windows. If I simply run 'pip install shapely', I get "No matching distribution found for shapely"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: Apparently you can use pip to install those. Sorry, bit out of my experience. I only use Python on Linux.

Comment: Not a duplicate, I know how to install a .whl file but the problem is that there seems to be no .whl file here.

Comment: That's weird, because when I go to that link I download a .whl file.

Comment: When I `unzip` it, it unzips into a couple of directories full of `.py` files, so I imagine you could just unzip that into your `site-packages` somewhere.

Comment: I renamed the .zip into a .whl and ran it using pip. It worked. Strange but good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your browser must have renamed the file during download - Christoph Gohlke only posts `.whl` files on his site.

Comment: `.whl` files are zip files (first two bytes are `PK`), so don't unzip it and re-name back to that extension (assuming your browser had fiddled around with it)

Answer (score -1):

The file is a .whl, you can install it by running

```
pip install ___.whl
```