# Cannot install pillow on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I keep getting errors when I try to run pillow on x64 Windows

I have followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) for installing pillow

I seem to able to

```
import PIL
```

but it fails when I try

```
from PIL import image
```

See screen shot
[image]

Can someone please help?

I've tried installing the 32 bit version, but that fails and trying to uninstall pillow also fails

[image]

Comment: That wheel ending in `_amd64.whl` is for 64bit version of python, but you have 32 bit one.

Comment: Oh dear I'm confused. My windows laptop is "x64-based PC". Does this mean I need to reload python, or change to 32 bit version of pillow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

All I needed to do was

```
pip install pillow
```

That simple