# GMPY2 Not installing, mpir.h not found

Tags: python, windows, installation, gmpy

I am trying to install gmpy2 on my Anaconda Python 3.5 distribution using pip. I was able to install other modules such as primefac perfectly. When I try to install gmpy2 this is what I get:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install gmpy2
Collecting gmpy2
  Using cached gmpy2-2.0.8.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gmpy2 ... error
  Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HADIKH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hd7b270n\\gmpy2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\HADIKH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplefsjn80pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'gmpy2' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMPIR -DWITHMPFR -DWITHMPC "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda3\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda3\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tcsrc\gmpy2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\gmpy2.obj
  gmpy2.c
  c:\users\hadi khan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hd7b270n\gmpy2\src\gmpy.h(104): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpir.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gmpy2
```

I have noticed that whenever I try installing gmpy2 on a computer I always get some sort of error and it is a different one every time. Can someone please tell me how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I maintain `gmpy2` and unfortunately I have not been able to build Windows binaries for Python 3.5 and later. `gmpy2` relies on either the MPIR or GMP libraries, and the MPFR and MPC libraries. There are detailed instructions included in the source distribution but they are not trivial to build on Windows. It is probably impossible(*) to build MPIR, MPFR, and MPC via pip. I would use the pre-compiled binaries available from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

(*) I'm sure it is possible with enough effort but I haven't done it.

Comment: I'm trying to use gmpy2 as well, are you telling me that it would work if I downgrade to python 3.4.10 or something?

Answer (score 18):

The reason is some required packages (especially below packages) aren't installed.

- GMP: GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library
- MPFR: GNU Multiple-precision floating-point rounding library
- MPC: GNU Multiple-precision C library

you could install those packages by below commands:

```
apt-get install libgmp-dev
apt-get install libmpfr-dev
apt-get install libmpc-dev
```

I could install gmpy2 by installing those libraries.

the key point is remembering below hint when you got an error like above.

`#  include "***.h": ==> No such file or directory`

> apt-get install lib"***"-dev

Comment: in windows you can install pip with cygwin and when installing cygwin's packages remember to install above packages and python/python-setuptools.

Comment: On a Mac:

`brew install gmp`
`brew install mpfr`
`brew install mpc`

Comment: solved my problem installing gmpy2
    include "mpfr.h"                                                                                                                           
          |            ^~~~~~~~                                                                                                                           
    compilation terminated.                                                                                                                               
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 3):

The answer above works as noted, but i had to also find out how to install a wheel, which is answered here [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)
specifically, by copying the wheel file and executing (in my case), using pip 9

pip install C:\Python35\gmpy2-2.0.8-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Comment: first i tried
gmpy2-2.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
but got success only with
gmpy2-2.0.8-cp39-cp39-win32.whl

Answer (score 1):

[image]Use conda to install instead of pip. conda will take care of installing the necessary dependencies. The command is: conda install gmpy2