# Installing gmpy2 on windows using pre-compiled binaries

Tags: python, gmpy

I am trying to install the gmpy2 package as its an requirement for the PHE package. As suggested in "[GMPY2 not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075271/gmpy2-not-installing-mpir-h-not-found?newreg=1e7f1cf78f36424d88a625a82b7484a7)", I have tried to install it via pre-compliled binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

However when I try to install it via

> pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

I get the following result:

> C:\Users\adria\Desktop>pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
>
> Requirement 'gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
>
> > Processing c:\users\adria\desktop\gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
> >     Exception:
> >     Traceback (most recent call last): (...)

Is it a problem that the download from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is saved as zip file?

I use Python 3.6.3 on Win10.

Comment: Indeed, you must unzip the .zip file, and run `pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` inside the directory holding the file

Comment: The unzip file is an .pyd file.
Im just unable to get this whl file.

Comment: Download it from this link : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy

Comment: I know. But the result is a zip file, but I think I need to convert it into a whl file to install it in this way, but I don't know how. Thanks and sorry I am quite new.

Comment: I have finally worked around it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to install without specifying the file extension (*i,e* : `pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64`) it won't work cause it will try to download the package from pypi repository:

```
C:\Users\bobolafrite\Downloads>pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64

Collecting gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
```

But if you try with the extension (*i,e* : `pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`)

```
C:\Users\bobolafrite\Downloads>pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Processing c:\users\bobolafrite\downloads\gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
    Installing collected packages: gmpy2
    Successfully installed gmpy2-2.0.8
```

Comment: Thank you so far.
Using: C:\Users\adria\Desktop>pip install : gmpy2-2.0.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Results in:
Invalid requirement: ':'
Traceback (most recent call last): ...

Comment: Whoops sorry don't know why I typed this ":" . It should never appear in a pip command. I edited my post

Comment: Thanks @bobolafrite. I wasted an hour trying to install gimpy2 for Python3 and this worked a treat. btw I needed to use pip3 in place of pip.