# Python virtualenv install requirements - Version not satisfied

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

Following the steps provided in the following SO answer: [Duplicate virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7438771/1964317), the following error keeps occurring for multiple packages.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ....

Specifically for all the packages that have to do with `anaconda/conda`. But also multiple others.

I've tried to remove from the list all the packages that caused the mentioned error, then the terminal finishes collecting the rest of the packages and calls:

`Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy2`

Which ends with the following message:
`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

I'm interested in duplicating an existing custom environment that was created using `virtualenv`. If there's a solution based on `conda virtual environments`, that could work as well.
According to the answers I've looked up, using `virtualenvwrapper` to duplicate the environment is not the best option however, I'm aware that I could probably use it as a last resort.

Comment: did you try [virtualenv-clone](https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone)?

Comment: To be clear, you created a new ```venv``` and tried to ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` after activating your new environment and it threw the error above?

Comment: @lwileczek Correct. I'll take a look at `virtualenv-clone`, Thanks. Still if there is a way to get the `requriements.txt` to work, I would prefer it.

Comment: Also check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075271/gmpy2-not-installing-mpir-h-not-found). Finally, [conda wheel-files](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/wheel-files.html) docs might help since there seems to be where it gets hung

Comment: maybe [pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/)  can help, it locks versions more precisly, from what I understand