# Python 3.7: Unable to install gmpy2 in a venv in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-venv, gmpy

I'm trying to install `gmpy2` in a virtual environment in Windows 10.

Initially, I was getting the following error.

```
Collecting gmpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/f4/9a2e384b325b69bc5827b9a6510a8fb4a51698c915c06a3f25a86458892a/gmpy2-2.0.8.zip
Installing collected packages: gmpy2
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: started
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-p2f519dp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\include\site\python3.7\gmpy2'
         cwd: C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\gmpy2\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'gmpy2' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-p2f519dp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\include\site\python3.7\gmpy2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I was able to go past this error by installing the *Build Tools for Visual Studio* from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

I tried again and this time I got the following error.

```
Collecting gmpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/f4/9a2e384b325b69bc5827b9a6510a8fb4a51698c915c06a3f25a86458892a/gmpy2-2.0.8.zip
Installing collected packages: gmpy2
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: started
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i495p48z\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\include\site\python3.7\gmpy2'
         cwd: C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\gmpy2\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'gmpy2' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DMPIR -DWITHMPFR -DWITHMPC -IC:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\include -IC:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\gmpy2.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\gmpy2.obj
    gmpy2.c
    C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\gmpy2\src\gmpy.h(104): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpir.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\biles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\gmpy2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\biles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i495p48z\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Workspace\path\to\project\venv\include\site\python3.7\gmpy2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried specifying the version to `2.1.0a4` and then to `2.1.0a2` and then to `2.0.8`. But I got the same error.

**Note:** I'm trying to install this package through *PyCharm Settings -> Project Interpreter*.

Comment: I think you need to install mpi library. mpir.h is not found

Comment: @keiv.fly - How can I install that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075271/gmpy2-not-installing-mpir-h-not-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `gmpy2` in Windows 10

1. Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and download *Build Tools for Visual Studio*
2. Run the downloaded executable and install the latest libraries for C++
3. Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and download the binaries for `gmpy2` corresponding to your version of Python
4. Install the wheel using the below-mentioned command.

   ```
   pip install C:\path\to\wheel\gmpy2-2.0.8-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
   ```

Using these steps I was able to successfully install `gmpy2` in my virtual environment. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image: installing gmpy2]

**Note:** In my case it was `gmpy2-2.0.8-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl` because my project interpreter was `Python 3.7`. The `cp37` in the filename means `CPython 3.7`. If you don't get the correct binaries, you'll get the following error.

```
gmpy2-2.0.8-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Thanks [@keiv.fly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3596337/keiv-fly) :)