# PyCharm won't install gmpy2 - Tried all versions

Tags: python, pycharm, gmpy

I am trying to install the package called gmpy2, but PyCharm just won't. Tried googling and can't find anything that helps me (or I might just not be doing it right).

I'm using Python 3.9 with PyCharm.

Here's a picture of what PyCharm gives me as a error popup, and what it says:

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Collecting gmpy2
  Using cached gmpy2-2.0.8.zip (280 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for gmpy2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: gmpy2
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: started
    Running setup.py install for gmpy2: finished with status 'error'
    
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ys292k4o\\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ys292k4o\\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h157haka\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\gmpy2'
         cwd: C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ys292k4o\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'gmpy2' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMPIR -DWITHMPFR -DWITHMPC -IC:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\gmpy2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\gmpy2.obj
    gmpy2.c
    C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ys292k4o\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\src\gmpy.h(104): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpir.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ys292k4o\\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ys292k4o\\gmpy2_8475706ea077495daaefe9d081e1ffff\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h157haka\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\gmpy2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image: PICTURE OF PYCHARM POPUP ERROR WINDOW]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GMPY2 Not installing, mpir.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075271/gmpy2-not-installing-mpir-h-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install it with **conda** or apt or any other package manager.

Comment: Thanks that helped!
Installed Anaconda as interpreter and thereafter just searched for the gmpy2 package, and then it was installed...
Thanks a lot!