# Python 2.7.12 - ImportError: No module named pyeda.inter

Tags: python-2.7

I have installed Python 2.7.12 on my PC. So I run python using cmd, while the .py file is on my desktop, and the python is placed at C:\Python27.

I want to import Pyeda in my codes, but the cmd said ImportError: No module named pyeda.inter. I am too new to python, so I want to ask if I can do something to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
from pyeda.inter import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library isn't installed by default. On Windows you'll need to download and install the binaries from the [PythonLibs page of Christoph Gohlke’s site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Installation instructions for other OSes can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyeda).

Comment: After downloading the file, then what should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Answer (score 0):

Just install the [library PyEDA](https://pypi.org/project/pyeda/) using the following command line `pip3 install pyeda`